# Attach a CSV in Mail

Tags: email, grails, csv

I want to attach a csv file in mail(grails)

The file in the path is already present. I am using the following code

```
sendMail {
    multipart true
    from "$senderName <$fromAddress>"
    to toAddress
    cc message.cc
    subject message.subject
    body content.plaintext
    html content.html
    attachBytes './web-app/ReadyOrdersFor-${vendor.name}','text/csv', new File('./web-app/ReadyOrdersFor-${vendor.name}').readBytes()
}
```

Error prompted is.
***java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./web-app/ReadyOrdersFor-${vendor.name}.csv (No such file or directory)***

neither this works prompting the same error

**attachBytes './web-app/ReadyOrdersFor-${vendor.name}.csv','text/csv', new File('./web-app/ReadyOrdersFor-${vendor.name}.csv').readBytes()**

Comment: Are you sure that this file exists for specified path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you trying you use the file path string as a GStringImpl, but the string is enclosed in single quotes. GStringImpl is natively supported in groovy in double quotes.

You code should be

```
attachBytes "./web-app/ReadyOrdersFor-${vendor.name}",'text/csv', new File("./web-app/ReadyOrdersFor-${vendor.name}").readBytes()
```

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761498/whats-the-difference-of-strings-within-single-or-double-quotes-in-groovy) should help you understand the difference between using single and double quotes in groovy.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to get a `File` reference using `new File(path)`, use the Spring [ResourceLoader](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader.html) interface. The `ApplicationContext` implements this interface, so you can get a reference to it from a controller (for example) like this:

```
class MyController implements ApplicationContextAware {

  private ResourceLoader resourceLoader

  void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    resourceLoader = applicationContext  
  }

  def someAction() {
    String path = "classpath:/ReadyOrdersFor-${vendor.name}"
    File csvFile = resourceLoader.getResource(path).file
  }
}
```

I'm not 100% sure the `path` value above is correct, you may need to remove the '/'