# Gradle Single vs Double Quotes

Tags: kotlin, gradle, groovy, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm new to gradle and am currently just trying to follow the tutorials and quite a few times I've seen single and double quotes intermixed. I just wanted to know if there was a difference of when one set should be used over the other. One example of this is section 6.12 of the tutorial - [Default tasks](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html):

```
defaultTasks 'clean', 'run'

task clean << {
    println 'Default Cleaning!'
}

task run << {
    println 'Default Running!'
}

task other << {
    println "I'm not a default task!"
}
```

So, I would just like to know if I should be paying attention to these differences or if they are inter-changable and I can use either single or double quotes when printing strings in gradle.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761498/whats-the-difference-of-strings-within-single-or-double-quotes-in-groovy

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Gradle build scripts are written in Groovy. Groovy has both double-quoted and single-quoted String literals. The main difference is that double-quoted String literals support String interpolation:

```
def x = 10
println "result is $x" // prints: result is 10
```

You can learn more about Groovy String interpolation in [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groovy_%28programming_language%29#String_Interpolation) or other Groovy articles on the web.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. But now I have a follow up question, is there any reason to not always use double quotes then?

Comment: Mostly subjective/situational ones like "looks better", "used to this style from another language", "want to use literal `$` or `"` without having to escape them", "easier to type". Many Groovy users seem to prefer single quotes by default. I prefer double quotes because they allow me to add/remove String interpolation without changing the quotes. Also I'm used to double quotes from languages like Java.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you can use one or the other. The only difference is that double-quoted strings can be GStrings, which can contain evaluated expressions like in the following example taken from [the Groovy documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Strings+and+GString):

```
foxtype = 'quick'
foxcolor = ['b', 'r', 'o', 'w', 'n']
println "The $foxtype ${foxcolor.join()} fox"
// => The quick brown fox
```

Comment: Double-quoted string literals are `GString`s iff they contain a `$`. Otherwise, they are plain `String`s.

Answer (score 7):

According to the gradle [docs](https://guides.gradle.org/style-guide/#favor_single_quotes_for_plain_strings_in_build_script_listings):

> **Favor single quotes for plain strings in build script listings**
>
> This is
> mostly to ensure consistency across guides, but single quotes are also
> a little less noisy than double quotes. Only use double quotes if you
> want to include an embedded expression in the string.

Comment: Looks like that guide and guidance has disappeared.

Comment: @DaveL. Yeah, and I can't find it anywhere else.

Comment: Found some similar guidance here - https://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html

"Last but not least, prefer using single quoted strings when you need string constants, and use double quoted strings when you are explicitly relying on string interpolation."

Comment: imo, mixing is much more noisy than only using double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Single-quoted strings are a series of characters surrounded by **single quotes**.
like :

```
def str='a single quoted string'
println str
```

Ouput :

```
a single quoted string
```

Whereas Double-quoted strings allow us the **String interpolation**
Here, we have a string with a placeholder referencing a local variable:

```
def name = 'Guillaume' // a plain string
def greeting = "Hello ${name}"
```

Output : `Hello Guillaume`

In your code,If you want to print the task name. So in that case, you need to use Double-quotes:

```
defaultTasks 'clean', 'run'

task clean << {
    println 'Default Cleaning!'
}

task run << {
    println "Default Running $run.name!"
    // here Double Quotes are required to interpolate task-name
}

task other << {
    println "I'm not a default task!"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) files (like *build.gradle.kts* or *settings.gradle.kts*) are regular Kotlin code.
So, string literals are always wrapped in double quotes:

```kotlin
val myFirstString = "4 / 2 equals ${4 / 2}"
val mySecondString = """The property "hide" was not found"""
```