# How to create a library project in Android Studio and an application project that uses the library project

Tags: android-studio

How do I create an Android Library Project (e.g. com.myapp.lib1) and the application project (e.g. com.myapp.app) and make the build system include com.myapp.lib1 on the application project?

I went to the Project Structure -> Modules -> My App project and added a dependency to the lib project. IntelliJ now can recognize classes from the lib project when used in the app project, but when I run the app project, there are errors like:

```
Gradle: error: package com.myapp.lib1 does not exist
```

Comment: I was using Android Libraries to build Free/Paid versions of my app. The new Gradle build system makes this approach obsolete with the Build Variants concept. You can now automatically build different signed APKs out of the same code. I wish I had known this sooner.

Comment: @theczechsensation--can you elaborate? After uploading APK for full version, I tried to upload APK for free version, but using same package name. Google Play Store (GPS) gave me message saying I'd already used that package name. Does what you say about gradle mean I don't need two separate apps in two separate packages?

Comment: Here is the perfect answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31366602/1118772. 

Aqib Mumtaz mentioned in the answers, but it is at last. Instead of wasting time on other ways, you can go with this.

http://www.philosophicalhacker.com/2014/10/02/an-alternative-multiproject-setup-for-android-studio/#comment-1176

Comment: Interesting [thread adding Libraries](http://hessan.annahid.com/game-development-days/day-9/).with pictorial explanation.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

To create a library:

File > New Module

select Android Library

[image: Lib]

To use the library add it as a dependancy:

File > Project Structure > Modules > Dependencies

[image: dep]

Then add the module (android library) as a module dependency.

[image: add module]

Run your project. It **will** work.

Comment: This creates the module's files within the project. What if you want the module to be external to the project so that it can be used with another application?

Comment: @rrbrambley: I've found a way to re-use a module in multiple projects. I created (NTFS Junction) folder links using an application called winbolic link for Windows. When I have a module that I would like to re-use in multiple projects, I create a folder link to the to-be-reused project inside the directory of each project in which to use it. After this I add the module dependency (in Andr. Studio). Now I can use/edit the module in each project while keeping is in sync. Not sure if it is the right way to go, but for now it seems to work quite well! This works better than a local maven repo.

Comment: Unfortunately, as of July 2014, there is no longer a Project settings like the one shown in the screenie.  I had to go edit the .grade files as in GrkEngineer’s answer below.

Comment: This should be down voted as this creates a module from within an existing project

Comment: If you want to use same lib in other projects, you have to copy the library module to that project and to configure settings.gradle and main module's build.gradle manually.

Comment: This is so wrong - you can create whatever you like if you have a project opened. But if you start from the Android Studio start screen, there are no library/module projects at all, only App projects. Why, Google...

Answer (score 119):

I wonder why there is no example of stand alone jar project.

In eclipse, we just check "Is Library" box in project setting dialog. 
In Android studio, I followed this steps and got a jar file.

1. Create a project.
2. open file in the left project menu.(app/build.gradle): *Gradle Scripts > build.gradle(Module: XXX)*
3. change one line: `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` -> `'apply plugin: com.android.library'`
4. remove applicationId in the file: `applicationId "com.mycompany.testproject"`
5. build project: *Build > Rebuild Project*
6. then you can get aar file: *app > build > outputs > aar folder*
7. change `aar` file extension name into `zip`
8. unzip, and you can see `classes.jar` in the folder.
   rename and use it!

Anyway, I don't know why google makes jar creation so troublesome in android studio.

Comment: Works for me on Android Studio 2.2.2 dec. 2016.

Answer (score 99):

Google’s Gradle Plugin recommended way for configuring your gradle files to build multiple projects has some shortcomings If you have multiple projects depending upon one library project, this post briefly explain Google’s recommended configuration, its shortcomings, and  recommend a different way to configure your gradle files to support multi-project setups in Android Studio:

[An alternative multiproject setup for android studio](http://www.philosophicalhacker.com/2014/10/03/an-alternative-multiproject-setup-for-android-studio/)

**A Different Way :**

It turns out there’s a better way to manage multiple projects in Android Studio. The trick is to create separate Android Studio projects for your libraries and to tell gradle that the module for the library that your app depends on is located in the library’s project directory. If you wanted to use this method with the project structure I’ve described above, you would do the following:

1. Create an Android Studio project for the StickyListHeaders library
2. Create an Android Studio project for App2
3. Create an Android Studio project for App1
4. Configure App1 and App2 to build the modules in the StickyListHeaders project.

The 4th step is the hard part, so that’s the only step that I’ll describe in detail. You can reference modules that are external to your project’s directory by adding a project statement in your settings.gradle file and by setting the projectDir property on the ProjectDescriptor object that’s returned by that project statement:

[image]

The code one has to put in `settings.gradle`:

```
include ':library1'
project(':library1').projectDir = new File('../StickyListHeader/library1')
```

If you’ve done this correctly, you’ll notice that the modules referenced by your project will show up in the project navigator, even if those modules are external to the project directory:

[image]

This allows you to work on library code and app code simultaneously. Version control integration also works just fine when you reference modules externally this way. You can commit and push your modifications to the library code just like you can commit and push modifications to your app code.

This way of setting up multiple projects avoids the difficulties that plague Google’s recommended configuration. Because we are referencing a module that is outside of the project directory we don’t have to make extra copies of the library module for every app that depends on it and we can version our libraries without any sort of git submodule nonsense.

Unfortunately, this other way of setting up multiple projects is very difficult to find. Obviously, its not something you’ll figure out from looking at Google’s guide, and at this point, there’s no way to configure your projects in this way by using the UI of Android Studio.

Comment: This is the perfect answer. Thanks.

Comment: thank you, i've been struggling with this for the last half hour!

Comment: Good answer, but you should be copying the relevant bits from the post to your answer in case the link breaks.

Comment: @GreysonP I have updated answer as per your suggestion.

Comment: @yuku Could you please review this answer as accepted answer. Its new way of doing project setup. Thanks.

Comment: **NOTE:** for string evaluation in gradle you must use double quote ("). This "save the day" for me. Linked to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171049/gradle-single-vs-double-quotes)

Comment: How do we reference the library code from the app code? After following your set up instructions, the app code still cannot refer to a package in the library code. Is there an extra step that needs to be done?

Comment: This is the correct answer. Library project reuse across multiple projects can be done this way.

Comment: @CEGRD You need to go to File > Project Structure and click on the name of the module you are working on. Then go to the dependencies tab > click on the '+' then 'Module dependency' in the drop down menu. You should then be able to add the library1 module to your current project.

Comment: This is the answer everyone is really searching for. THANK YOU

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. This should be the accepted answer and the official way how to manage library modules in multiple projects.

Comment: I have been scouring the internet for this answer for weeks. This is the best way. No local maven repository, no git submodules, no combining all your repositories - just editing your code back like you did in Eclipse. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 46):

Check out this [link about multi project setups](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Multi-project-setup).

Some things to point out, make sure you have your settings.gradle updated to reference both the app and library modules.

settings.gradle: `include ':app', ':libraries:lib1', ':libraries:lib2'`

Also make sure that the app's build.gradle has the followng:

```
dependencies {
     compile project(':libraries:lib1')
}
```

You should have the following structure:

```
 MyProject/
  | settings.gradle
  + app/
    | build.gradle
  + libraries/
    + lib1/
       | build.gradle
    + lib2/
       | build.gradle
```

The app's build.gradle should use the `com.android.application` plugin while any libraries' build.gradle should use the `com.android.library` plugin.

The Android Studio IDE should update if you're able to build from the command line with this setup.

Comment: Is the plugin defined in build.gradle the only difference? i.e. Can you change an existing module into an Android library by changing that one line?

Comment: One day, we will click an import button and the library will just work, then we will begin typing code in the editor.

Comment: This  approach seems to include the libraries within the actual project. What the OP wanted was to know how to create a seperate Android library project that lives in its own project/space and only included on the main app project as a lib

Comment: @SteveM That has been my problem throughout my career. I just start coding without any design. And then spend hours debugging and refactoring.

Answer (score 14):

For Intellij IDEA (and Android Studio) each library is a Module. Think of a Module in Android Studio as an equivalent to project in Eclipse. Project in Android Studio is a collection of modules. Modules can be runnable applications or library modules.

So, in order to add a new android library project to you need to create a module of type "Android library". Then add this library module to the dependency list of your main module (Application module).

Answer (score 13):

The simplest way for me to **create** and **reuse** a library project:

1. On an opened project `file > new > new module` (and answer the UI questions)

[image]

2. check/or add if in the file **settings.gradle**: `include ':myLibrary'`
3. check/or add if in the file **build.gradle**:

   `dependencies {
        ...
        compile project(':myLibrary')
    }`
4. To reuse this library module in another project, copy it's folder in the project instead of step 1 and do the steps 2 and 3.

**You can also create a new studio application project**
 You can easily change an existing application module to a library module by changing the plugin assignment in the build.gradle file to com.android.library.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {...}
```

to

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {...}
```

more [here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/create-project.html#SettingUpLibraryModule)

Comment: If you change an existing application module to a library module by changing the plugin assignment, you'll also have to remove the line `applicationId "com...." from the gradle file.

Comment: "WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'."

Answer (score 10):

You can **add a new module** to any application as **Blundell** says on his answer and then reference it from any other application.

If you want to move the module to any place on your computer just move the module folder (modules are completely independent), then you will have to reference the module.

To reference this module you should:

- On build.gradle file of your app add:

  ```
  dependencies {
  ...
  compile project(':myandroidlib')
  }
  ```
- On settings.gradle file add the following:

  ```
   include ':app', ':myandroidlib'
   project(':myandroidlib').projectDir = new File(PATH_TO_YOUR_MODULE)
  ```

Comment: for example `project(':library').projectDir = new File('../library')` where `library` is the folder name in parallel with the android project's folder.

Answer (score 6):

Don't forget to use `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` in your `build.gradle` instead of apply plugin: `'com.android.application'`

Answer (score 5):

## [Documentation Way](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html)

This is the recommended way as per the advice given in the Android Studio documentation.

#### [Create a library module](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html#CreateLibrary)

Create a new project to make your library in. Click **File > New > New Module > Android Library > Next > (choose name) > Finish**. Then add whatever classes and resourced you want to your library.

When you build the module an AAR file will be created. You can find it in `project-name/module-name/build/outputs/aar/`.

#### [Add your library as a dependency](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html#AddDependency)

You can add your library as a dependency to another project like this:

1. Import your library AAR file with **File > New Module >  Import .JAR/.AAR Package > Next > (choose file location) > Finish**. (Don't import the code, otherwise it will be editable in too many places.)
2. In the settings.gradle file, make sure your library name is there.

   ```
   include ':app', ':my-library-module'
   ```
3. In the app's build.gradle file, add the compile line to the dependencies section:

   ```
   dependencies {
       compile project(":my-library-module")
   }
   ```
4. You will be prompted to sync your project with gradle. Do it.

That's it. You should be able to use your library now.

## Notes

If you want to make your library easily available to a larger audience, [consider using JitPac or JCenter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41847740/3681880).

Answer (score 4):

Had the same question and solved it the following way:

**Start situation**:

```
FrigoShare (root)
|-Modules:    frigoshare,   frigoShare-backend
```

**Target**: want to add a module named `dataformats`

1. Add a new module (e.g.: `Java Library`)
2. Make sure your `settings.gradle` look like this (normally automatically):

   `include ':frigoshare', ':frigoShare-backend', ':dataformats'`
3. Make sure (*manually*) that the `build.gradle` files of the modules that need to use your library have the following dependency:

   `dependencies {
           ...
           compile project(':dataformats')
       }`

Answer (score 4):

Purpose: Android library at single place - Share across multiple projects
http://raevilman.blogspot.com/2016/02/android-library-project-using-android.html

Answer (score 3):

As theczechsensation comment above I try to search about Gradle Build Varians and I found this link: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-gradle-build-variants--cms-25005
This is a very simple solution. This is what I did:
 - In build.gradle:

```
flavorDimensions "version"

productFlavors {
    trial{
        applicationId "org.de_studio.recentappswitcher.trial"
        flavorDimension "version"
    }
    pro{
        applicationId "org.de_studio.recentappswitcher.pro"
        flavorDimension "version"
    }

}
```

Then I have 2 more version of my app: pro and trial with 2 diffrent packageName which is 2 applicationId in above code so I can upload both to Google Play. I still just code in the "main" section and use the getpackageName to switch between to version. Just go to the link I gave for detail.

Answer (score 2):

There are two simplest ways if one does not work please try the other one.

1. Add dependency of the library inside dependency inside build.gradle file of the library u r using,  and paste ur library in External Libraries.

OR

2. Just Go to your libs folder inside app folder and paste all your .jar e.g Library files there Now the trick here is that now go inside settings.gradle file now add this line "include ':app:libs'" after "include ':app'" It will definitely  work...........:)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, using MAC OS X 10.11 and Android 2.0, and by doing exactly what Aqib Mumtaz has explained.

But, each time, I had this message : "*A problem occurred configuring project ':app'. > Cannot evaluate module xxx : Configuration with name 'default' not found*."

I found that the reason of this message is that Android 2.0 doesn't allow to create a library directly. So, I have decided first to create an app projet and then to modify the build.gradle in order to transform it as a library.

This solution doesn't work, because a Library project is very different than an app project.

So, I have resolved my problem like this :

- First create an standard app (if needed) ;
- Then choose 'File/Create Module'
- Go to the finder and move the folder of the module freshly created in your framework directory

Then continue with the solution proposed by Aqib Mumtaz.

As a result, your library source will be shared without needing to duplicate source files each time (it was an heresy for me!)

Hoping that this help you.