# Proper way to add global library in android-studio/gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

First of all, I know how to add a **local** library to the `build.gradle` file, it was discussed in several questions here already (which are all basically the same), see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16593391/android-studio-and-using-external-library-projects), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779959/android-studio-importing-external-library-jar) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16614177/how-to-add-parse-to-an-android-studio-project). But you have to hardcode the paths in the `compile files('/path/to/lib.jar')` statements in the `build.gradle` file, which isn't nice, not redistributable, etc, IF you use a library not within the project's folder structure. I prefer to maintain this library for all my projects in the same place (so it is always up to date for all projects etc.). So I would like to know how to add a library, which is not available via Maven, to an Android-Studio project using gradle, in a sane way, given that the library is added as a global library in AS's preferences.

What I have done so far:

I use Google's new Android-Studio, which uses gradle for the build management, to build an [Xposed framework module](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1574401). For that, I have to include an external library, `XposedLibrary`, which I downloaded from the respective [Github repository](https://github.com/rovo89/XposedMods) to keep it up-to-date.

It contains the jar `XposedLibrary/XposedBridgeApi.jar`, which I added in AS as a *global library* (Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S -> Global Libraries -> green plus to add the folder `XposedLibrary`). The compilation failed, complaining that it doesn't know the imported classes. So I had to manually add the library to the `build.gradle` file, adding the respective line in the dependencies like so:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('/home/sebastian/dev/android/XposedMods/XposedLibrary/XposedBridgeApi.jar')
}
```

I tried out to just add `compile files('XposedBridgeApi.jar')` or `compile files('XposedLibrary/XposedBridgeApi.jar')` but this didn't work.

So, what is a nice way to add an AS global library to the dependencies without using full paths? (I don't like the idea of symlinking to the jar file from within the `lib/` folder ;) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This post describes how to get XposedBridgeApi.jar working with Gradle in Android Sudio: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=41904291&postcount=1570

Answer (score 6):

when referencing a file via

```
files("relative/path/to/a.jar")
```

the relative path is evaluated relative to the buildscript this snippet is in. so when your build.gradle file is located in let's say '/a/project/build.gradle' then the jar should be in '/a/project/relative/path/to/a.jar'. In a multiproject gradle build you can put the the jar in  a folder relative to the root - project and reference it in all subprojects via

```
rootProject.files("relative/to/root/a.jar")
```

hope that helps,
cheers,

René

Answer (score 1):

I think here is the proper way:
[Import Xposed in Android Studio](http://blog.czbix.com/import-xposed-in-android-studio.html)

Edit the /app/build.gradle like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    provided fileTree(dir: 'deps', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use "provided files('src/XposedBridgeApi-54.jar')" as the lib isn't allowed to be included in the module, because the XposedBridge is already installed on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

With Android Studio, you have to first understand that the IDE uses the same model for a project that your command line build (gradle) uses. That is why the Project Structure dialog has a pop up that says edits here will have no effect. So adding a global library will also have no effect.

The correct way to fix such issues is to edit your gradle build scripts so that the command line gradle build works properly. Then you should just have to click on "Tools | Android | Sync Project with Gradle files" menu item to refresh the project structure in the IDE.

Finally, if your dependencies are not going to be in Maven Central, then you'd have to create a local maven repository. Read the thread here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/adt-dev/eCvbCCZwZjs/vGfg-4vNy9MJ for background.