# Create Android Library to use in 2 apps

Tags: android, version-control, shared-libraries, android-library

I have about 7 classes which are needed for my 2 apps.
I'm using Android Studio 0.3.1 and I want to create 2 projects which are using these classes.

My concern lies with version-control, since I want my 2 apps in seperate repositories to be up to date, the moment I commit changes to the 7 classes. I don't want to merge these classes by hand in my 2 repositories.

Is there anybody who can help me with my situation?

Thank you!

EDIT: The classes are extending Android classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a library project for those shared classes - [How to create a library project in Android Studio and an application project that uses the library project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601299/how-to-create-a-library-project-in-android-studio-and-an-application-project-tha)

and put it into version control.

then in each of your other 2 projects include that project as a dependency.

if you're using Git, you can add it as a Git submodule, so its independent of the actual apps repositories.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Isn't it so that if you create a module like in your link, the module is added as a subfolder of the project? This makes it hard to put under version control.

Comment: you need to exclude the subfolder from version control. or add it as a sub repository (version control software dependent, if you're using Git it can be added as a Git submodule)