# Android Studio reuse module library at other project

Tags: java, android-studio

I have a module with some POJO classes that is marked at gradle as apply plugin: 'java' .Is there a way to reuse it at another project ? Everything i tried failed . (I dont want to copy pasta it)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue recently.

This is how I resolved the code redundancy problem:

1. Create a new Android Studio project 'libs' and add all my APIs in a 'library' module.
2. In build.gradle of your library module, add code to upload the artifact to local Maven repo.

`

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
group = 'com.<example>'
version = '1.0'

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "file:///Users/<myuser>/.m2/repository")
        }
    }
}
```

`

3. The archive is uploaded in your maven repo as aar file.
4. Use this aar file in any other project as a dependency.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two other questions on the same matter.

[How do I add a library project to Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio)

[How to create a library project in Android Studio and an application project that uses the library project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601299/how-to-create-a-library-project-in-android-studio-and-an-application-project-tha)

Personally I didn't use any of the two provided methods.
I built my project as a JAR, added it to the 'libs' folder, right clicked on it and clicked 'Add as library' and then finally added the dependency in the gradle file like so:

```
dependencies {

    compile files('libs/MyJAR.jar')

}
```

Comment: project doesnt produce a jar . I cant find a way. The only thing i get is apk for whole project not the module I need. Solutions dont work for me.

Comment: @Parhs Unfortunately you can't reuse an APK file in your project. Your best shot is to create a [library project.](https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects)

Comment: this seems what I need. I should select android library ? However not sure if it is compatible with older android version

Comment: Just make sure that your android library requires the same or lower API level then your new project.