# Android Studio referencing library seems overly complicated. Is there an easier way?

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to migrate to Android Studio from Eclipse.

In reading a simple example of using a library within another app:
https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-build.html

In eclipse to achieve this all I would go to the properties of the project and add a reference to the project. Simple, through the IDE and easy to check the build settings at a later date.

In Android Studio I've got to add an entry to my referenced library using ALT-ENTER after getting autocomplete to find the library, which seems to add an entry to the file 'app.iml':

```
<orderEntry type="module" module-name="app2" />
```

Then I've got to edit the gradle file:

```
dependencies {
 compile project(":lib")
}
```

Is there not a better way, i.e. using the IDE. I don't particularly want to have to remember about this xml iml file or have to manually edit build files every time I want to do something.

?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, 
After browsing for a while with no answer I found it just after posting:
[How to create a library project in Android Studio and an application project that uses the library project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601299/how-to-create-a-library-project-in-android-studio-and-an-application-project-tha)

Why can't Google update their documentation to use the more normal way (presuming this dialog is a new addition)....