# Android Studio include library project and keep up to date

Tags: android, module, android-studio

I have a shared library project which is used by multiple projects and I don´t want to import it in those projects, as it always makes a copy of the original one, which means that the library, once imported, isn´t up to date.

My second attempt was to only include the jar of the library project which should be build automatically, but I can´t move out of the current project with the file chooser of android studio.

How can I share the current state of my library with multiple projects without using maven or similar?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601299/how-to-create-a-library-project-in-android-studio-and-an-application-project-tha) helps?!

Comment: This is the common way of using libraries. It only helps if all modules are in the same project

Comment: Does library project use gradle?