# layout xml in library project and child projects

Tags: android, android-layout, library-project

My app uses a library project "**core project**" with the application core, then little projects "**child projects**" for the particularities of each supported device, ie. Amazon Fire TV, Kindle tablets, regular google tablets, phones, etc.

Let's say, I have a Custom View class `MyCustomView` that inflates programmatically a layout `R.layout.layout_customview`. **Both are on the core project:**

```
public class MyCustomView {
     .
     .
     inflate (R.layout.layout_customview);
     .
     .
}
```

I'd like to create an alternative layout for this custom view in one of the child projects, so I created the `layout_customview.xml` and put it **into the child project res/layout.**

However, the custom view keeps inflating the other one under the core project res/layout (sounds logical after all, as they both reside in the same project).

Is there a way to change this behavior? ie. "override" xml layout files, or do I have to give the alternative layout a different name, extend the class, etc..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In cases where a resource ID is defined in both the application and
>   the library, the tools ensure that the resource declared in the
>   application gets priority and that the resource in the library project
>   is not compiled into the application .apk. This gives your application
>   the flexibility to either use or redefine any resource behaviors or
>   values that are defined in any library.

[Managing Projects](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects)

I guess the better course here is just to duplicate the xml in your projects.

Comment: humm... however that's not happening, can it be because the class using the resource resides in the library project as well?

Comment: What is happening exactly? Can you clarify again the place of the class and the place of the xml?

Comment: All stuff is in the core project (library project). I create a child project and just create a XML with the same name, but the class keeps inflating the one from the library project! The link you posted is clear, it should be inflating the other one!

Comment: Try creating a new project and then adding your 'library' as a module? http://stackoverflow.com/a/16617332/2058534 . I haven't worked with this scenario but I'm guessing that your library is being read as the main app?

Comment: at the end I just did it the old-skool way, ie, extending the class & using a different name, my projects are pretty complex and I'd lose a lot of time for this experiment if I have to create a new one, etc.. And I'm suspecting it may be related to the resource being loaded from a different resolution folder, I have like 15 folders of those ... I'm accepting your answer because it answers the question with the official docs from Android, so my problem should be elsewhere !

Comment: It's probably something to do with the structure. In normal cases you should be able to redefine any resource from the library just fine. Good luck