# How do I set up an Android Studio project for a jar library?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm creating a jar library that will be imported into Android projects. How do I set up an Android Studio project to output a JAR instead of an APK? This project contains none of the usual Android components (Activities, Services ...etc.) but it will be imported into my Android projects and I'd still like to use the same IDE for both.

On the other hand, if I export my library as an APK, is it possible to import it into other Android projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup your first project as a library, and then include it as a lib on your app. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601299/how-to-create-a-library-project-in-android-studio-and-an-application-project-tha).