# How to create Android library in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-library

I am trying to build a library for android.

My problem is that when i try to create a new project, only thing i can do is to create a new app.

I did try to Create New Module, there i can create a library for android, but only inside an app.

I want to create a library to be used with many apps.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: there is a good explanation here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601299/how-to-create-a-library-project-in-android-studio-and-an-application-project-tha)

Comment: This question hasnt been answered at all from the previous question that was asked.