# Android studio 1.0.1 how to create library project

Tags: android, android-studio

In Eclipse, you can simply press right key on project, select property->Android->isLibrary to create a library project, but in Android studio 1.0.1, how to create a library project?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add a library project to the Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27380270/library-project-in-android-studio-1-0/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create library project in Android Studio, go to

```
File -> New Module -> Android Library
```

Comment: All I see when I open AS is "Start New Project" and that seems to insist on creating an Application.

Comment: @Almo You are right. To get access to "File" menu you need to create of open Android Project.