# How can I add a dependency to my Android project without getting an error?

Tags: android, module, android-studio, dependencies, android-library

I want to create an Android Library module and make that a dependency of my current project. I've tried the answer of the following question: [How to create a library project in Android Studio and an application project that uses the library project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601299/how-to-create-a-library-project-in-android-studio-and-an-application-project-tha)

When I tried to run my app, the following message showed up:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I'm using Android SDK tools 24.1.2. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Changing (installing) the JDK location to **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67** solved the problem for me.