# Android Studio TOP LEVEL EXCEPTION

Tags: java, android

I have an App that depends on this other module. "Make project" works, but trying to run it results in this error: [image]

Similar answers point to the gradle files, so here is a ss of them:

[image]

I have no idea what is going on. I followed very simple steps on how to create a java library for my android project from this question: [How to create a library project in Android Studio and an application project that uses the library project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601299/how-to-create-a-library-project-in-android-studio-and-an-application-project-tha) and haven't been able to find my mistake so far.

Comment: I might have had similar problems and the solution was to include that library in gradle differently. But maybe this is completly unrelated, I am just throwing some sticks...

Comment: set multiDexEnabled=true.

Comment: Probably like `dexOptions {
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }` in the correct `gradle` file...