# Can I use the local gradle cache (or something else) to speed up Android library development?

Tags: maven, caching, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, aar

I am developing a Android library, and I am looking for guidance on how to speed up the mechanics of developing the library for use in an application.

In my production workflow, I publish the `aar` library to a private maven repository. This `aar` library is retrieved through gradle by multiple applications. This works fine for production.

I am looking for a good development workflow to use development versions of the library. These are the options I have identified, none of which I find entirely satisfactory:

1. Publishing each development library version to the private maven repository. Continually publishing development versions of the library to the maven repository and retrieving them to run once in a test application is very cumbersome because this requires either using a new version for every development version or wiping the local gradle cache when reusing the same version.
2. [Copying the source of the library into the source of the project, described in the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16601299/4107809). This seems to defeat the purpose of having a library.
3. [Switching the application to use a local file version of the `aar` library.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24506648/adding-local-aar-files-to-gradle-build-using-flatdirs-is-not-working) Importing the `aar` library introduces changes to the build files of the application that need to be reverted when going back to the production use of the maven repository.

Is there a way I can insert my development versions of the `aar` library into the local gradle cache so they can be retrieved locally, while maintaining the same application build configuration present in the production version? Or is there a simpler workflow for library development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution for library development was to upload to maven, and clear one the corresponding entry in the local gradle cache. See [Is there a simple way to remove one dependency from the local gradle cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36507115/4107809).