# Is there a simple way to remove one dependency from the local gradle cache?

Tags: caching, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

The local gradle cache stores copies of maven/gradle dependencies. [How to clear gradle cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23025433/4107809) covers how to clear the whole cache, but not individual packages.

Is there a simple way to remove one package from the local gradle cache? This would be useful, for example, when actively developing a library. To test a minor library change, I currently have to clear the entire cache from the filesystem so an old cached version of the library is not used.

I understand it is also possible to use the [gradle ResolutionStrategy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html) described in [How can I force gradle to redownload dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13565082/4107809). I would prefer not to change the gradle configuration because most of the time and for most developers, the default caching behavior is fine.

Comment: is there a reason you do not want to use `--refresh-dependencies` ?

Comment: @RaGe Because this ignores ALL cache entries. I want to ignore one entry, not all of them.

Comment: understood, although the blanket ignore is probably the simplest way to (over)do this.

Comment: You said you also do not want to make changes to build.gradle, would you be open to running a different gradle script?

Comment: @RaGe Yes, though hopefully that does not involve forking the existing gradle script.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So here's a quick script I whipped up:

#### seekanddestroy.gradle

```
defaultTasks 'seekAndDestroy'

repositories{ //this section *needs* to be identical to the repositories section of your build.gradle
    jcenter() 
}

configurations{
    findanddelete
}

dependencies{
    //add any dependencies that  you need refreshed
    findanddelete 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.2'
}

task seekAndDestroy{
    doLast {
        configurations.findanddelete.each{ 
            println 'Deleting: '+ it
            delete it.parent
        }
    }
}
```

You can invoke this script by running `gradle -b seekanddestroy.gradle`

---

Demo of how it works:
if your build.gradle looks like this:

```
apply plugin:'java'

repositories{
    jcenter()
}

dependencies{

    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.2'
}
```

First time build, includes a download of the dependency:

```
λ gradle clean build | grep Download
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/commons/commons-math3/3.2/commons-math3-3.2.jar
```

Second clean build, uses cached dependency, so no download:

```
λ gradle clean build | grep Download
```

Now run seekanddestroy:

```
λ gradle -b seekanddestroy.gradle  -q
Deleting: .gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.commons\commons-math3\3.2\ec2544ab27e110d2d431bdad7d538ed509b21e62\commons-math3-3.2.jar
```

Next build, downloads dependency again:

```
λ gradle clean build | grep Download
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/commons/commons-math3/3.2/commons-math3-3.2.jar
```

Comment: Is `findanddelete` a built-in? I don't see it in Gradle 6

Comment: @SridharSarnobat No, It's a custom configuration defined in the example code in this answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Saved the day! Looks like -b is getting deprecated. Hope they will come up with a permanent solution.

Answer (score 3):

Works great, but for newer versions of gradle, use this instead:

```
task seekAndDestroy{
    doLast {
        configurations.findanddelete.each{ 
            println 'Deleting: '+ it
            delete it.parent
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The only problem is why does gradle not implementing this for us, instead of expecting us to implement it ourselves.  Removing a dependency is such a common thing that it seems weird to miss out this feature in gradle.