# having two different apks from the same project

Tags: android

i have and android project with a flag that depending on its value the functionality of the applicaiton changes. the thing is I want to have two apks (the two functionalities) on the phone, so how is it possible to have the 2 apks on the same phone
regards,

Comment: Do you know how to use product flavours in android studio ?

Comment: no, is there a link or something??

Comment: Do you mean this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package

Comment: Not possible you should create different projects and build them extra

Comment: thanks guys this is what i needed

Comment: Yes it is possible. You have to add module into your main project.

Comment: I recommend you to use android studio, Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601299/how-to-create-a-library-project-in-android-studio-and-an-application-project-tha

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. I suggest you to have 1 apk, 1 starter activity that starts the right behavior depending on the value of the flag!

Comment: not possible, the changes are within the same activity and 2 apks are needed

Comment: Split that activity in 2 activity