# How to avoid it appears two icons after installing a APP that dependent to another project?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a project that dependents to another project for using it common classes. I refer the settings method from here:
[How to create a library project in Android Studio and an application project that uses the library project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601299/how-to-create-a-library-project-in-android-studio-and-an-application-project-tha)

After I complete the dependencies settings, the project structure becomes this:
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rD4DN.png) The "app" is the main APP and "CH_BC_Lib" is the dependent project. But "CH_BC_Lib" project is a APP too, it has itself MainActivity. And when I build the .apk and install on a device, it comes out two icons with same icon picture and APP name:[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oayTu.png)

Maybe I should modify more settings? Below is the AndroidManifest.xml of two project.

app:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.kinpo.ch.lib_tester"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="18"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/f2_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

CH_BC_Lib:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.ch_bc_lib"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="18"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.ch.general.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: you have Two launcher Activity. that is why. remove one of the intent-filter and you are good to go.

Comment: Remove launcher activity from library project.

Comment: Thanks, it fix the problem. But is it possible fix without change dependent project code? :p