# How to import the content of an application to another android studio?

Tags: java, android

I have made a main application. To this application I want to add a keyboard. So I made a keyboard in another project. The question is how I could let my keyboard be imported in the main application. I hope I was clear enough. And thanks for answering

Comment: can you elaborate your question pls ?

Comment: Have you tried this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601299/how-to-create-a-library-project-in-android-studio-and-an-application-project-tha)?

Comment: +Magesh Pandian I have made a keyboard for my app but in another application. I want the keyboard to be available for the first app.It's a custom keyboard. How do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build your keyboard app as a library, and add it as a module in the Main Project.

Follow the steps below to import your keyboard project as a library;

- Copy the content of your Keyboard project folder inside the Main Folder of the Parent project,make the following changes to the Keyboard project folder

a. Delete everything inside the folder leaving just the app directory.

b. Cut all the content of the app directory and drop it outside the app 
     directory so that your keyboard project folder has something like dis

[image: Structure of your keyboard library after deleting the unneeded files]

c. Open the build.gradle and apply android plugin as a library 
`apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`

- Open settings.gradle in the main project folder and include your library `include ':app', ':keyboard'`
- Open your main app build.gradle and add it to the dependencies like this `compile project(':keyboard')`

I hope i didnt miss any steps, with this your keyboard is seen as a library in your Main App

Comment: I'll try this and I'll reply to you.

Comment: For some kind of reasons, I'm unable to convert the keyboard to a library. I replaced in the build.gradle the apply plugin: 'com.android.library' but the file built is an apk? Could you help me providing a step to step tutorial?

Comment: Alright I will edit my answer with a step by step process,in a bit.

Comment: @RtsAyat You're welcome! ...kindly mark as answer and upvote.