# Local maven dependency not found by gradle in android studio

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Android studio cannot find a dependency which is obviously in my local repository. Error:

> Error:Failed to find: com.poppy:tutti-frutti-dtos:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT Open File
> Open in Project Structure
>   dialog

I am using the gradle wrapper and Android studio 1.0.2. I have double checked the name of my dependency and I have the following build.gradle file for the project. I have also tried with mavenLocale() which doesn't not seem to work either. Any advice to debug this?

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'D:/Users/Math/.m2/repository' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects{
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'D:/Users/Math/.m2/repository' }
    }
}
```

Here is the dependency section of the module build.gradle file of my project:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11'
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.2'
compile 'com.poppy:tutti-frutti-dtos:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.+'
}
```

My library is located here: D:\Users\Math.m2\repository\com\poppy\tutti-frutti-dtos\1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
And there are four files under that folder:

- _remote.repositories
- maven-metadata-local.xml
- tutti-frutti-dtos-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
- tutti-frutti-dtos-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom

Comment: Can you post the build.gradle file from the module also (or at least the dependency section)?  Thanks.

Comment: @AndroidGuy done. Is it correct to define the repositories in the parent only? I guess so...

Comment: Putting the repository at the parent level is the typical way to do it.  The Android Studio wizards generate the build scripts that way.

Comment: Can you show that the library actually is in the local repository under the correct name?  Maybe you could list the directory structure under ".m2".  Is the library there?  Or is the name of the library different than what the dependency expects?

Comment: Also, may I ask why you are putting the library directly in ".m2".  I know that this isn't your question but I'm just curious.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that specifying a directory for a maven URL is supposed to work? Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882804/adding-local-aar-files-to-my-gradle-build

Comment: @Scott Barta I am pretty sure it is valid at least because I fill the value library in the Project settings in Intellij and he automatically create this line for me in the build.gradle file.

Comment: You might try looking at http://stackoverflow.com/a/20962300/990066 which seems to suggest that you may need a bit more setup to use maven local.

Answer (score 0):

path is not match Math/.m2 -> Math.m2

```
maven { url 'D:/Users/Math/.m2/repository' }

D:\Users\Math.m2\repository\com\poppy\tutti-frutti-dtos\1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```