# android gradle plugin - offline installation

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have to install android gradle plugin on offline PC

from googling a lot I understand I can do it via local maven repository.
but from unsuccessfully tryings and from all the QA about this issue I understand it's not simple.
I've never worked with maven.
Do anyone who experienced with do it could help me please and write the needed steps?

thank you for giving your time

Answer (score 0):

Using mavenLocal() is not that complex as you think

1. You need to add `mavenLocal()` as a repository location in the main build.gradle
2. since you want it to search in the local maven , make sure its the first option in the repositories section .
3. Double check the correct version your using and the Use of the appropriate extension of the dependency
4. Now gradle will try to download the dependency from mavenLocal (.m2 folder)

for example , you should have something like this

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
```

Now you can publish to your maven local with

```
gradlew build publishToMavenLocal
```

Then having the same setup , you download with no connection needed .

Comment: thank you very much for your response. could you explain please how do I add the android gradle plugin to the local repository ? should I use the pom file? how? I feel  stupied but tried a lot and can't understand

Comment: i have really never came across the same situation , but my experience with mavenLocal was when i used the [pygradle plugin](https://github.com/linkedin/pygradle) and faced a bug ,so i had to download the whole repo , did some modification , and then publish to my maven local  , then use the updated version with the bug fixed , i think what you need to do , is to do it once online , and then try to locate the plugin with the .m2 , then do this to the offline side and add it to .m2 on the offline device , not sure though that this will work .