# Gradle copy method not working when $buildDir.parent is used

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I need to execute a copy task before an integration test and this is how I am doing it.

```
    println "project dir is" +  "${buildDir.parent}"//this line prints the path of the directory fine when i run the script

    //here is my copy method which needs to run before the test task
    test.doFirst {
        copy {
            from '${buildDir.parent}/test/xx.xml'

            into '${buildDir.parent}/build/classes/test'

             }
        }
```

Below is the output on the console when I run gradle test:

Output: *the project directory isC:\Users\xxx\git\xyz\xyz\xxx*

However when I run the test task the file is not getting copied

Please help!

Comment: You ar talking about files but you just trying to copy one file xx.xml. Is it correct?

Comment: I have many copy methods in the doFirst, but they are all similar copy methods so I just posted one of those methods for convenience of reading.

Comment: @SanDroid Corrected!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved! I was using single quotes which don't support string interpolation.

Reference: by peter niederwieser at [Gradle Single vs Double Quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171049/gradle-single-vs-double-quotes)