# gradle fileTree with variable dir

Tags: variables, gradle, filetree

I am not sure if this is supported by fileTree. I searched the document and all examples used concrete (absolute or relative) paths.  This is what I want to do.

```
ext {
    externalProjectRoot "c:/AnotherProject"
}

implementation fileTree(dir: ${externalProjectRoot}/lib', include: '*.jar')
```

If I do the following, it works.

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'c:/AnotherProject/lib', include: '*.jar')
```

So I suspect that the fileTree function doesn't support variable for the dir attribute.  If not, what other options do I have?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `"` instead of `'` :

replace

```
implementation fileTree(dir: '${externalProjectRoot}/lib', include: '*.jar')
```

with

```
implementation fileTree(dir: "${externalProjectRoot}/lib", include: '*.jar')
```

See more explanation about difference between use of ' and " in this answer: [Gradle Single vs Double Quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171049/gradle-single-vs-double-quotes) :

> Gradle build scripts are written in Groovy. Groovy has both double-quoted and single-quoted String literals. The main difference is that double-quoted String literals support String interpolation