# How to set a version on a variable out of dependencies tag with Gradle?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, version

I want to **set the version of my dependencies in just one place in my Gradle** *(app/build.gradle)* configuration file , to became easier to change in case of a update.

the problem is:

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:12.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0'
}
```

Can you see that, i'm repiting the same version many times and this make slow and unprodutive to change all version to the next version.

Like in Maven i could just do like this:

```
<properties>
    <org.springframework.version>5.0.8.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
</properties>
```

After set the version, I just add like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The last piece of Maven configuration did set the version in this parte:

> ${org.springframework.version}

How can I do the same in my gradle configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the assumption, that they'd all would have the same version is categorically wrong ...

```
def glideVersion = "4.5.0"

dependencies {

    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1"

    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0"

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4"

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.3"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.3"

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4"

    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:${glideVersion}"
}
```

one can also set `project.ext` [properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html) with version numbers - or load them from external files.

```
ext {
    glideVersion = "4.5.0"
    ...
}
```

and then use it with `${rootProject.ext.glideVersion}` or `${project.ext.glideVersion}`.

in general, it's not easier to change... just another way of organizing it.

Comment: @Dims as already stated in previous comments, you need double quotes `"`... at least when evaluating expressions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171049/gradle-single-vs-double-quotes

Comment: Okay thank you it worked. Also can you explain please, why in the same context `nd4j_version` and `"${nd4j_version}"` refers to different variable?

Comment: @Dims can only guess, without seeing the script, but `def` defines a local variable - which might be defined with another value, within another scope. within the same scope, it should always be the same.

Comment: I refer to your code. You wrote `ext { glideVersion`, but in strings you wrote `${project.ext.glideVersion}` not `${ext.glideVersion}`. You got exta nesting, specified nowhere. Why?

Comment: Also why didn't you wrote `ext { def glideVersion = `?

Comment: @Dims because the one defines a Gradle project's extra properties and the other a local Groovy variable. http://groovy-lang.org/documentation.html (Gradle DSL is based upon that).

Comment: The question is not about definition, but about usage. Why does path in expansion string different than in direct usage (for the same way of definition)

Comment: @Dims because it is root project and sub project (module) - of which each have their own `ext` "extra properties". depending where one defines variables/properties, one has to refer to them accordingly. eg. one could even define local variables in a sub project, and initialize them with root project extra properties. here I often use a `version.properties` file, which I load in the root project and then reference in sub projects (which I'd consider the most organized way of managing the version numbers).

Comment: I think @dims alread anwsered, but `ext` is default from gradle, one right way for use. Def ise common from Groovy.

Comment: @ShamFiorin it depends where/when one has to access the variable or property.