# How to set JAR version with variable in Gradle?

Tags: gradle

How to set JAR version with variable in Gradle?

If I write

```
ext.nd4j_version = "1.0.0-beta2"
ext.nd4j_backend = "nd4j-native-platform"

dependencies {

    compile group: 'org.nd4j', name: '${nd4j_backend}', version: '${nd4j_version}'
```

it is unable to find artifacts.

And if I write

```
nd4j_version = "1.0.0-beta2"
nd4j_backend = "nd4j-native-platform"

dependencies {

    compile group: 'org.nd4j', name: '${nd4j_backend}', version: '${nd4j_version}'
```

then it is able to find artifact, but issues a warning

```
Could not set unknown property 'nd4j_version' for root project
```

**UPDATE**

The following also doesn't work

```
ext.nd4j_version = "1.0.0-beta2"
ext.nd4j_backend = "nd4j-native-platform"


dependencies {

    compile group: 'org.nd4j', name: '${project.ext.nd4j_backend}', version: '${project.ext.nd4j_version}' // works
```

and the following

```
ext.nd4j_version = "1.0.0-beta2"
ext.nd4j_backend = "nd4j-native-platform"


dependencies {

    compile group: 'org.nd4j', name: '${rootProject.ext.nd4j_backend}', version: '${rootProject.ext.nd4j_version}'
```

and the following

```
ext {
    nd4j_version = "1.0.0-beta2"
    nd4j_backend = "nd4j-native-platform"
}


dependencies {

    compile group: 'org.nd4j', name: '${project.nd4j_backend}', version: '${project.ext.nd4j_version}'
```

Please give an answer with an explanation, not just random working syntax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a version of dependencies on Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53000509/how-to-set-a-version-of-dependencies-on-gradle)

Comment: `"${project.ext.nd4j_version}"` should work (the location of the variable definition  in the `build.gradle` matters, because it either has refer to `project` or to `rootProject`).

Comment: @MartinZeitler how would I know this from Gradle doc without reading it in it's entirety?

Comment: much of that only gets obvious while working with it. would suggest to add `ext {nd4j_version = "1.0.0-beta2"}` to the root project's `build.gradle` and then reference it within a module as `"${rootProject.ext.nd4j_version}"` ...which makes sense, when occasionally having to update several modules.

Comment: eg. `compile "org.nd4j:nd4j-native-platform:${rootProject.ext.nd4j_version}"` ...but this only makes sense with several modules; for a single module, it's sufficient to define it at the module level. the `"` is important there, else there won't be any string substitution.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `'{$}'` and use the variable as it is.

```
ext.nd4j_version = "1.0.0-beta2"
ext.nd4j_backend = "nd4j-native-platform"

dependencies {
   compile group: 'org.nd4j', name: nd4j_backend, version: nd4j_version
```

EDIT: You can also use double-quotes with `${}`:

```
dependencies {
   compile group: 'org.nd4j', name: "${nd4j_backend}", version: "${nd4j_version}"
```

Comment: Okay, but what if I want to use `$`?

Comment: Edited my answer! :)

Comment: Ok it doesn't work for me: if variables prepended by `ext`, it can't find them with `${variable_name}`

Comment: What version of `Gradle` are you using?

Comment: Why version can matter? Can you explain why `nd4j_backend` works and `'${nd4j_backend}'` doesn't? Why it takes names from different contexts?

Comment: note that  `'${nd4j_backend}'` cannot work as you need to use `"` character to enable string interpolation,  see more details here : http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_double_quoted_string