# how to to find a string in groovy list

Tags: grails, groovy

question from a groovy newbie:

sql is initiated as follows

```
 final Binding binding = new Binding();  
 binding.setProperty("sql", sql);
final groovy.sql.Sql sql = Sql.newInstance(dbConfig.getUrl(), dbConfig.getUserName(), dbConfig.getPasswd(),"oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
```

I am running a query in groovy like this

```
def listOfRows = sql.rows (select column1 from table1);
```

listOfRows when printed shows contents like `[[column1_name:value1], [column1_name:value2], [column1_name:value3]]`

I want to check if `value2` (a String) exists in the returned list of values from the above query.

I have tried doing `listOfRows.contains('value2')` and `listOfRows.find('value2')`,
it complains that the method does not exist for lists..

what's the best way of doing this ?

EDITED: I have corrected the list of printed values. What's being returned is `List<GroovyResultSet>`
and I have also added the definition of sql.

Comment: What's your definition of `sql`?

Comment: What does listOfRows actually contain? It can't be `[column1_name:value1, column1_name:value2, column1_name:value3]`

Comment: I second @tim_yates, `[column1_name:value1, column1_name:value2, column1_name:value3]` is not even a map, since `keys` are same. Are you getting a list of such maps with keys as column1, column2, ....?

Comment: I stand corrected, what's being returned is list<GroovyResultSet>
Correction - listOfRows when printed shows contents like [[column1_name:value1], [column1_name:value2], [column1_name:value3]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i ended up doing is following :

iterate the listOfRows, get all the values for column1 from each GroovyResultSet into a listOfValues ,then check for my values in that list.

```
def listOfValues=[];
listOfRows.collect(listOfValues){it.getAt('column1')};
if(listOfValues.size()==3){
  println('success');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to take a look at groovy documentation, and particularly to collections documentation (both [tutorial](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Collections) and [JDK](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/)/[GDK](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/)).

in that case, the most specifically adapted solution would be to use [`Collection#find()`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#find%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) ... with something like

```
listOfRows.find { it.contains(':value2') }
```

Which can be translated into human-readable

find the first element in this collection which string contains ":value2".

Comment: In 2021, those links are broken. This is the most appropriate "modern" one: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/working-with-collections.html

Answer (score 1):

You probably want

```
listOfRows.column1.contains( 'value2' )
```

Comment: just to add that: listOfRows is list of maps with your data read from the DB. with colums names as keys and the expression `listOfRows.column1` (equivalnet to `listOfRows['column1']` converts the map in a list with the content of all the rows for the 'column1'.

Comment: As I mentioned I am Groovy newbie, I cann't figure out the correct syntax for doing this ..
(a) listOfRows.column1.contains( 'value2' )
(b) listOfRows['column1'].contains( 'value2' )
neither works..

Answer (score 0):

You are probably invoking [this method](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/sql/Sql.html#rows%28groovy.lang.GString%29) which takes a GString (note that *GString != String*) as an argument. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761498/whats-the-difference-of-strings-within-single-or-double-quotes-in-groovy), a string in single quotes is a standard java string, and a string in double quotes is a templatable string.

```
'hello'    //java.lang.String
"hello"    //groovy.lang.GString
```

Try this:

```
listOfRows.contains("value2")
```