# Access a Groovy variable from within shell step in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Using the [Pipeline plugin in Jenkins 2.x](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/overview/), how can I access a Groovy variable that is defined somewhere at stage- or node-level from within a `sh` step?

Simple example:

```
node {
    stage('Test Stage') {
        some_var = 'Hello World' // this is Groovy
        echo some_var // printing via Groovy works
        sh 'echo $some_var' // printing in shell does not work
    }
}
```

gives the following on the Jenkins output page:

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test Stage)
[Pipeline] echo
Hello World
[Pipeline] sh
[test] Running shell script
+ echo

[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

As one can see, `echo` in the `sh` step prints an empty string.

A work-around would be to define the variable in the environment scope via

```
env.some_var = 'Hello World'
```

and print it via

```
sh 'echo ${env.some_var}'
```

However, this kind of abuses the environmental scope for this task.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference of strings within single or double quotes in groovy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761498/whats-the-difference-of-strings-within-single-or-double-quotes-in-groovy)

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but I think it's a simple matter of using the correct quotes. The examples given in the page you linked use double quotes: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/overview/#basic-groovy-syntax-for-pipeline-configuration

Comment: Indeed, thank you for pointing this out. Should have looked more carefully... when using double quotes, the interpolation works as expected. You might add this as an answer if you like.

Comment: @Dirk Your workaround is actually the correct way to do it safely: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#injection-via-interpolation

Answer (score 89, accepted):

To use a templatable string, where variables are substituted into a string, use double quotes.

```
sh "echo $some_var"
```

Comment: For sh env vars we must do sh "echo \$some_var"

Comment: Warning: A secret was passed to "sh" using Groovy String interpolation, which is insecure.
   Affected argument(s) used the following variable(s): [GIT_PASSWORD, GIT_USERNAME]
   See https://jenkins.io/redirect/groovy-string-interpolation for details.

Comment: I have been looking into a pipeline script for so long before I managed to fix it... your response was a part of the solution, thank you, sir! :)

Comment: It helps me. Using double quotes like `sh "echo $file_name"` in groovy passes variable to another shell command.

Comment: Please note that this is vulnerable to [injection via interpolation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#injection-via-interpolation). The workaround suggested in the question is actually the safe way to achieve this. Double-quotes should generally be avoided unless you absolutely trust the contents of the variable in advance.

Answer (score 26):

I am adding the comment from @Pedro as an answer because I think it is important.

For sh env vars we must use

```
sh "echo \$some_var"
```

Comment: or simply : sh 'echo $some_var'

Comment: This solution did not work for me, only the one posted by @dave-bacher did

Answer (score 10):

You need to do something like below if a bash script is required :

Set this variable at global or local(function) level where from these can be accessible to sh script:

```
def stageOneWorkSpace = "/path/test1"
def stageTwoWorkSpace = "/path/test2"
```

In shell script call them like below

```
sh '''
echo ''' +stageOneWorkSpace+ '''
echo ''' +stageTwoWorkSpace+ '''
cp -r ''' +stageOneWorkSpace+'''/qa/folder1/* ''' +stageOneWorkSpace+'''/qa/folder2
'''
```

Make sure you start and end sh with three quotes like `'''`

Comment: This is more or less equivalent to Groovy string interpolation, and can be insecure in the general case. See problem and alternatives in the documentation: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#injection-via-interpolation

Comment: gives error if the variable does not exist in the ELSE block which it is not supposed to execute

Answer (score 3):

I would like to add another scenario to this discussion.
I was using shell environment  variables and groovy variables in the same script.

```
 format='html'
    for file in *.txt; 
        do mv  -- "\$file" "\${file%.txt}.$format";
    done
```

So here, What I have done is use \$ only for shell environment variables and use $ for groovy variables.

Answer (score 0):

This is extension to @Dave Bacher's answer. I'm running multiple shell command in Groovy file & want to use output of one shell command to the next command as groovy variable. Using double quotes in shell command, groovy passes variable from one to another command but using single quotes it does not work, it returns null.

So use shell command like this in double quotes: `sh "echo ${FOLDER_NAME}"`

```
FOLDER_NAME = sh(script: $/
    awk -F '=' '/CODE_COVERAGE_FOLDER/ {gsub("\"","");print$2}' ${WORKSPACE}/test.cfg
  /$, returnStdout: true).trim()

echo "Folder: ${FOLDER_NAME}" // print folder name in groovy console

sh "mkdir -p ${WORKSPACE}/${FOLDER_NAME} && chmod 777 ${WORKSPACE}/${FOLDER_NAME}"
```

Comment: When using `sh`, this can be vulnerable to [injection via interpolation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#injection-via-interpolation). In your case, `WORKSPACE` is already an environment variable so can be used directly in the shell. If you declare `env.FOLDER_NAME = ...` instead, you can then use single quotes: `sh 'mkdir -p "$WORKSPACE/$FOLDER_NAME" ...` (note: the double quotes belong to bash not the Groovy script, but can be useful if either `WORKSPACE` or `FOLDER_NAME` contain spaces)