# Pass groovy variable to shell script

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, cloudbees

I just started learning groovy.I want to pass the svnSourcePath and svnDestPath to shell script in the svn copy command. But URL not rendered.

```
node {
 stage 'Copy Svn code'

def svnSourcePath = "${svnBaseURL}${svnAppCode}${svnEnvDev}${SVN_DEV_PACKAGE}"
def svnDestPath = "${svnBaseURL}${svnAppCode}${svnEnvTest}${SVN_DEV_PACKAGE}"

print "DEBUG: svnSourcePath = ${svnSourcePath}"
print "DEBUG: svnDestPath = ${svnDestPath}"

withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: crendentialsIdSVN, passwordVariable: 'SVN_PWD', usernameVariable: 'SVN_USER']]) {
    sh '''  
    svn copy $svnSourcePath $svnDestPath -m 'promote dev to test' --username $SVN_USER --password $SVN_PWD '''
}  
}
```

Output

```
+ svn copy -m 'promote dev to test' --username techuser --password 'xxxyyy' 
     svn: E205001: Try 'svn help' for more info
     svn: E205001: Not enough arguments provided
```

Comment: To the person who downvoted this question - what's the point of downvoting without giving an explanation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39982414/access-a-groovy-variable-from-within-shell-step-in-jenkins-pipeline/66637408#66637408

Answer (score 14, accepted):

added the single quotes and plus operater('+ variable +') around the variable. Now it is working

```
svn copy '''+svnSourcePath+' '+svnDestPath+''' -m 'promote dev to test' --username $SVN_USER --password $SVN_PWD '''
```

Answer (score 6):

+1 to Selvam answer

following is my use case with parameter plugin

String parameter name: pipelineParameter

Default value: 4

```
node {
  stage('test') {
        withCredentials([[...]]) {
          def pipelineValue = "${pipelineParameter}"  //declare the parameter in groovy and use it in shellscript
          sh '''
             echo '''+pipelineValue+' abcd''''
             '''
        }
}}
```

The above prints 4 abcd

Answer (score 5):

You can use `""" content $var """`.  `"""` allows string interpolation in the here doc; `'''` does not.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like below if a bash script is required :

Set this variable at global or local(function) level where from these can be accessible to sh script:

```
def stageOneWorkSpace = "/path/test1"
def stageTwoWorkSpace = "/path/test2"
```

In shell script call them like below

```
sh '''
echo ''' +stageOneWorkSpace+ '''
echo ''' +stageTwoWorkSpace+ '''
cd ''' +stageOneWorkSpace+  '''
rm -r ''' +stageOneWorkSpace+ '''/AllResults
mkdir -p AllResults
mkdir -p AllResults/test1
mkdir -p AllResults/test2
cp -r ''' +stageOneWorkSpace+'''/qa/results/* ''' +stageOneWorkSpace+'''/AllResults/test1
cp -r ''' +stageTwoWorkSpace+'''/qa/results/* ''' +stageOneWorkSpace+'''/AllResults/test2
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

only one time double quotes would also work

```
stage('test') {  
  steps {  
    script {  
      for(job in env.JOB_NAMES.split(',')) {  
        println(job);  
        sh "bash jenkins/script.sh $job"  
        sh "echo $job"  
      }  
    }//end of script  
  }//end of steps  
}//end of stage test
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this question when I was looking for a way to interpolate a variable value in an `sh` command.

Neither Single-quoted `'string'` nor Triple-single-quoted `'''string'''` strings support interpolation.

[According to Groovy documentation:](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html)

> Single-quoted strings are plain java.lang.String and don’t support
> interpolation.
>
> Triple-single-quoted strings are plain java.lang.String and don’t
> support interpolation.

So to use the embedded string values in groovy ([GString](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/lang/GString.html)) the double quotes must be used, any GString within it will be evaluated, even if it was inside a single-quoted string.

```
    sh "git commit -m  'Build-Server: ${server}', during main build."
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def my_var = "hai"
sh (
    script:  "echo " + my_var,
    returnStdout: true
)
```