# Access a Groovy variable inside a generated parallel pipeline in a shell

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm stuck on accessing a groovy variable inside a shell step in Jenkins pipeline.

I read [Access a Groovy variable from within shell step in Jenkins pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39982414/access-a-groovy-variable-from-within-shell-step-in-jenkins-pipeline) and [Pass groovy variable to shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41553303/pass-groovy-variable-to-shell-script) but cannot have what I want working as expected.

Here is my pipeline:

```groovy
// While you can't use Groovy's .collect or similar methods currently, you can
// still transform a list into a set of actual build steps to be executed in
// parallel.

// Our initial list of strings we want to echo in parallel
def tempList = dusboard.split(',').collect{it as String}

def stringsToEcho = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

// The map we'll store the parallel steps in before executing them.
def stepsForParallel = tempList.collectEntries {
  ["echoing ${it}" : transformIntoStep(it)]
}

// Actually run the steps in parallel - parallel takes a map as an argument,
// hence the above.
parallel stepsForParallel

// Take the string and echo it.
def transformIntoStep(tmpBoard) {
  // We need to wrap what we return in a Groovy closure, or else it's invoked
  // when this method is called, not when we pass it to parallel.
  // To do this, you need to wrap the code below in { }, and either return
// that explicitly, or use { -> } syntax.
  return {
    node('tb-tftp-server') {
      echo tmpBoard
      stage('install') {
        env.board = tmpBoard
        lock(resource: "$tmpBoard") {
          sh '''
                hwjs="hw-\${board}.js"
                echo "1 $hwjs"
                hwjs="hw-\${tmpBoard}.js"
                echo "2 $hwjs"
            '''
        }
        lock(resource: "$tmpBoard") {
          sh '''
                echo ''' + tmpBoard + ' abcd' '''
         '''
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I execute it with **dus011,dus012** as input parameters (i.e. variable dusboard=dus011,dus012), here comes the output

```
[echoing dus011] Trying to acquire lock on [dus011]
[echoing dus011] Lock acquired on [dus011]
[Pipeline] [echoing dus011] {
[Pipeline] [echoing dus012] lock
[echoing dus012] Trying to acquire lock on [dus012]
[echoing dus012] Lock acquired on [dus012]
[Pipeline] [echoing dus012] {
[Pipeline] [echoing dus011] sh
[echoing dus011] [lionel_test3] Running shell script
[echoing dus011] + hwjs=hw-dus012.js
[echoing dus011] + echo '1 hw-dus012.js'
[echoing dus011] 1 hw-dus012.js
[echoing dus011] + hwjs=hw-.js
[echoing dus011] + echo '2 hw-.js'
[echoing dus011] 2 hw-.js
[Pipeline] [echoing dus012] sh
[echoing dus012] [lionel_test3@2] Running shell script
[Pipeline] [echoing dus011] }
[echoing dus011] Lock released on resource [dus011]
[Pipeline] [echoing dus011] // lock
[echoing dus012] + hwjs=hw-dus012.js
[echoing dus012] + echo '1 hw-dus012.js'
[echoing dus012] 1 hw-dus012.js
[echoing dus012] + hwjs=hw-.js
[echoing dus012] + echo '2 hw-.js'
[echoing dus012] 2 hw-.js
[Pipeline] [echoing dus011] lock
[echoing dus011] Trying to acquire lock on [dus011]
[echoing dus011] Lock acquired on [dus011]
[Pipeline] [echoing dus011] {
[Pipeline] [echoing dus011] sh
[echoing dus011] [lionel_test3] Running shell script
[Pipeline] [echoing dus012] }
[echoing dus012] Lock released on resource [dus012]
[Pipeline] [echoing dus012] // lock
[echoing dus011] + echo dus011 abcd
[echoing dus011] dus011 abcd
[Pipeline] [echoing dus012] lock
[echoing dus012] Trying to acquire lock on [dus012]
[echoing dus012] Lock acquired on [dus012]
[Pipeline] [echoing dus012] {
[Pipeline] [echoing dus012] sh
[echoing dus012] [lionel_test3@2] Running shell script
[Pipeline] [echoing dus011] }
[echoing dus011] Lock released on resource [dus011]
[Pipeline] [echoing dus011] // lock
[Pipeline] [echoing dus011] }
[echoing dus012] + echo dus012 abcd
[echoing dus012] dus012 abcd
[Pipeline] [echoing dus011] // stage
[Pipeline] [echoing dus011] }
[Pipeline] [echoing dus011] // node
[Pipeline] [echoing dus011] }
[echoing dus011] Failed in branch echoing dus011
[Pipeline] [echoing dus012] }
[echoing dus012] Lock released on resource [dus012]
[Pipeline] [echoing dus012] // lock
[Pipeline] [echoing dus012] }
[Pipeline] [echoing dus012] // stage
[Pipeline] [echoing dus012] }
[Pipeline] [echoing dus012] // node
[Pipeline] [echoing dus012] }
[echoing dus012] Failed in branch echoing dus012
[Pipeline] // parallel
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Also:   java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property '
             ' on null object
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property '
             ' on null object
```

We can see the lock command has the correct board: one time **dus011**, another time **dus012** ==> good

But this one is wrong **[echoing dus011] + hwjs=hw-dus012.js** it should be **hw-dus011.js**, not **hw-dus012.js**. I think it's because it's an environment variable and the second // stage overwrite the first one ==> bad

Other prints for board name are wrong.

So I tried with the '''++' syntax. Sounds good because this time board name matches **[echoing dus011] dus011 abcd** and **[echoing dus012] dus012 abcd** but then Java exception :(

Where is my mistake? how to solve that?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this could be happening because inside your parallel block you are modifying the global `env` variable by doing `env.board = tmpBoard`. You have a race condition between those blocks based on write/read access.

I think the best way to do this would be to instead use the `withEnv` inside of your blocks to isolate the context in which the environment is set.

Instead of

```groovy
env.board = tmpBoard
```

you could do

```groovy
withEnv(["board=$tmpBoard"]) {
    // block of code needing board as environment variable
}
```

Comment: Except the fact I used
    withEnv(["board=$tmpBoard"])
to expand tmpBoard into board it worked. Thanks a lot

Comment: Good catch, thanks for pointing that out @Lionelon . Edited the answer.