# How to pass a groovy variable to a shell block jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a groovy variable that i would like to pass to a shell block for further processing, but i keep getting the error pasted bellow:

```
stages {      
    stage('First Stage - echo out available variables'){
        steps{

            script {
                def string_var = "im a groovy variable"
                echo "${string_var}"   // This will print "im a groovy variable" just fine
                sh """
                    echo """ + string_var + """
                """  // This will error

                sh """
                    echo ${string_var} 
                """  // This will error

                sh ''' echo '''+ string_var +''' '''

                sh "echo ${string_var}" // This will error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My error:

```
an exception which occurred:
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv.locals
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@1ecb37ba
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CallEnv.caller
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallEnv@32070c3b
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.e
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable@641113f0
```

Comment: You need to define as `sh """
    echo string_var: ${string_var}
    """`

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41553303/pass-groovy-variable-to-shell-script

Comment: What are the parameter types of the sh method?  You may need to do this to get immediate evaluation of the GString: sh "echo $string_var".toString()

Comment: @RohitMahajan i tried that, same error, and on the link you posted, i tried the additional triple " and still got the same error., i will edit the code above to show what i just tried.

Comment: Triple double quotes is working for me. Can you please try `sh '''
             echo '''+ string_var +'''
             '''`

Comment: @RohitMahajan I just edited my code to show full example, i still am getting that error.

Comment: your script is broken. please fix it, missing triple single quotes

Answer (score 11):

I tried to use your pipeline (just closed `'''` scopes) and everything works fine:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {      
        stage('First Stage - echo out available variables'){
            steps{
                script {
                    def string_var = "im a groovy variable"
                    echo "${string_var}"

                    sh """
                        echo """ + string_var + """
                    """

                    sh """
                        echo ${string_var} 
                    """ 

                    sh ''' echo '''+ string_var +''' ''' // added '''

                    sh "echo ${string_var}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output for this pipeline:

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (First Stage - echo out available variables)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
im a groovy variable
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo im a groovy variable
im a groovy variable
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo im a groovy variable
im a groovy variable
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo im a groovy variable
im a groovy variable
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo im a groovy variable
im a groovy variable
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

So, probably the problem is in some other place of script, or you need to update Pipeline Plugin (I use 2.6 version) / Jenkins (I use 2.150.1 version).

Comment: I use pipeline plugin: 2.5 and jenkins 2.107.1 know of any bug fixes for your version?

Comment: Don't find any possible fixed bug yet (tried to find in [changelogs](https://jenkins.io/changelog-stable/)), but you can install local Jenkins with new version and check if the issue resolved.