# How to convert Jenkins string parameter to Terraform map variable?

Tags: jenkins, terraform, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, infrastructure-as-code

I'm trying to pass string parameter(s) to a Terraform map variable, but receiving error "Invalid number literal".  It's not quite clear how to access keys and values in Terraform maps when passing a Jenkins parameter via `terraform apply -var ...`

Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    parameters {
        string(name: 'IP1', defaultValue: '', description: 'Enter first IP address')
    }
    
    stages {
        stage('Git Checkout') {
            steps {
                git branch: 'branch1', credentialsId: '', url: 'http://<redacted>.git'
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy Terraform') {
            steps {
                script {
                        dir('Linux') {
                                sh """
                                terraform init
                                terraform plan
                                terraform apply -var 'vms=${params.IP1}' \
                                --auto-approve
                                """
                            }
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

variables.tf

```
variable "vm_map" {
  type = map(object({
    name = string
    ip   = string
  }))
  default = {
    "first" = {
      name = "ubuntu-jenkins1"
      ip   = "172.30.100.160"
    }
    "second" = {
      name = "ubuntu-jenkins2"
      ip   = "172.30.100.161"
    }
    "third" = {
      name = "ubuntu-jenkins3"
      ip   = "172.30.100.162"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54178737/3730626

Comment: Your immediate problem: incorrect syntax of passing string variable. It should be `terraform apply -var vms="${params.IP1}"`

Comment: Additionally, I'm not sure simple string with ip will be successfully applied to variable of described type, but I'm not an SME on terraform, so you'll need to wait for more informed opinion on that.

Comment: Your JP code and TF config are both completely fine unto themselves, and so you would need to add the error message so that we could assist with the difference between your expected and actual results when the two interface. Without the necessary information in the question the best guess is that the `Map` needs to be converted to a JSON string in the JP code for the TF CLI to parse it into a `map` within the `sh` step method.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Here's the error output:

Note: You didn't use the -out option to save this plan, so Terraform can't
guarantee to take exactly these actions if you run "terraform apply" now.
+ terraform apply -var vms=172.30.100.161 --auto-approve
[31m╷[0m[0m
[31m│[0m [0m[1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mInvalid number literal[0m
[31m│[0m [0m
[31m│[0m [0m[0m  on <value for var.vms> line 1:
[31m│[0m [0m  (source code not available)
[31m│[0m [0m
[31m│[0m [0mFailed to recognize the value of this number literal.
[31m╵[0m[0m

Comment: @markalex That still resulted in this error:

[31m│[0m [0m[1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mInvalid number literal[0m
[31m│[0m [0m
[31m│[0m [0m[0m  on <value for var.vms> line 1:
[31m│[0m [0m  (source code not available)
[31m│[0m [0m
[31m│[0m [0mFailed to recognize the value of this number literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!  You can substitute 'vm1' for any value that identifies the first map object.

```
terraform apply -var vms='''{vm1: {name: "ubuntu",ip: "${params.IP1}"}}''' --auto-approve
```

If you also wanted to add a name string parameter for the vm name, it would look like

```
terraform apply -var vms='''{vm1: {name: "${params.VM_NAME1}",ip: "${params.IP1}"}}''' --auto-approve
```

Here's the terraform apply for multiple vm's

```
terraform apply -var 'vm_map={"first": {"name": "ubuntu-jenkins1", "ip": "172.30.100.160"}, \
      "second": {"name": "ubuntu-jenkins2", "ip": "172.30.100.161"}, \
      "third": {"name": "ubuntu-jenkins3", "ip": "172.30.100.162"}}' --auto-approve
```