# How to to pass pipeline parameter to shell script

Tags: shell, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a groovy file which I need to use pipeline parameter in the shell script:

```
def call() {
    echo "current build number: ${currentBuild.number}"
    def pipelineValue = "${currentBuild.number}"
    sh '''
        cd /jenkins/jenkins/workspace/Run_Distribution_Self_Service/
        mkdir -p builds/{pipelineValue }/libs/jfrog_distribution_shared_lib/resources/com/amdocs/python_distribution_util
'''
```

How can I get the pipelineValue in the shell script and use it?

Comment: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_double_quoted_string

Comment: can you guide me where to look?

Comment: use double-quotes instead of single-quotes to interpolate groovy(pipeline) values into string. like this: `sh """ ... mkdir -p builds/${pipelineValue}/libs/... """`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct syntax:

```
mkdir -p builds/'''+pipelineValue+'''/libs/jfrog_distribution_shared_lib/resources/com/amdocs/python_distribution_util
```

the below link helped me:
[Pass groovy variable to shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41553303/pass-groovy-variable-to-shell-script)

Answer (score 0):

```
def call() {
echo "current build number: ${currentBuild.number}"
def pipelineValue = "${currentBuild.number}"
sh '''
    cd /jenkins/jenkins/workspace/Run_Distribution_Self_Service/
    mkdir -p builds/${pipelineValue}/libs/jfrog_distribution_shared_lib/resources/com/amdocs/python_distribution_util
'''
```