# Groovy parameter to shell script

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy

I've been trying to separate my code into two different files: `callTheFunction.groovy` and `theFunction.groovy`.

As you can see from the name of the file:

- `callTheFunction.groovy` calls the function defined in `theFunction.groovy`, passing random values in as parameters.
- `theFunction` is a shell script - inside groovy function - which is supposed to use the parameters passed from `callTheFunction`.

**PROBLEM:**
The shell script does not recognize/understand the arguments, the variables are empty, no value.

**theFunction.groovy**

```sh
def call(var1, var2) {
  sh '''
    echo "MY values $var1 and $var2"
  '''
}
```

**callTheFunction.groovy**

```
def call {
  pipeline {
    stages {
      stage ('myscript') {
        steps {
          theFunction("Value1", "Value2")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**OUTPUT FROM PIPELINE:**

```
MY values  and
```

I am aware that there are similar issues out there:

- [Pass groovy variable to shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41553303/pass-groovy-variable-to-shell-script)
- [How to assign groovy variable to shell variable](https://www.edureka.co/community/56903/how-to-assign-a-groovy-variable-to-a-shell-variable)

Comment: you have to read also about strings in groovy and what's the difference between single-quoted string and double-quoted string. https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#all-strings

Comment: What I should've added is: If I have the shell script in the same file as the variables it works. So if I define global variables `def var1 = "myvalue"` and `def var2 = "myothervalue`, and have the shell script in the same file, it works.

Comment: just replace quotes: `sh ''' ... '''` with `sh """ ... """`

Comment: Just got an example: Let's say I use `sh """ ... """`, what do I do if I got a for loop and `sed`, example: `for i in a b c; do sed -i '/^$i/d` myfile` --> This would not work, because when you use **triple-double-quotes** you have to escape the shell variables, meaning my sed would look like this: `sed -i '/^\$i/d myfile`.  `sed` is no longer looking for my variable `$i`, but instead the character `$` and `i`.

Comment: use [environment variables](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/environment/). or use `''' ... ''' + variable + ''' ... '''` to inject variable values

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATES**

You can use environment variable without having `environment {}`

Use environment variables like the ones i have used here (i refactored your code a little bit). Using triple single quotes for shell script for loop and adding grrovy variable to it:

```
def callfunc() {
  sh '''
  export s="key"
  echo $s
  for i in $VARENV1 
    do
      echo "Looping ... i is set to $i"
    done
    '''
}

pipeline {
    agent { label 'agent_1' }
    stages {
      stage ('Run script') {
        steps {
            script {
                env.VARENV1 = "Peace"
            }
            callfunc()
        }
      }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

Reference:
[Jenkins - Passing parameter to groovy function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63517881/jenkins-passing-parameter-to-groovy-function/63521293#63521293)