# Jenkins - Passing parameter to groovy function

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I've been trying to call another groovy function with parameters inside my pipeline without any luck.
The groovy function I am passing the parameters to consists of a bash script, but this bash script does not recognize the parameter(s) I am passing to it.  If however the parameter passed by i defined as a `parameters {}` in the pipeline, then it works, but I do not want this.

**PROBLEM:**
The shell script does not recognize/understand the arguments, the variables are empty, no value.

**pipelineJenkins.groovy**

```
def call {
  pipeline {
    parameters { 
      string (name: VAR1, defaultValue: "Peace", description: '' }  <--- This works, but not beneficial
      string (name: VAR2, defaultValue: "Space", description: '' }  <--- This works, but not beneficial
    stages {
      stage ('Run script') {
        steps {
          groovyFunction("${VAR1}", "${VAR2}")
          groovyFunction("Peace", "Space") <--- WHAT I WANT
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**groovyFunction.groovy**

```sh
def call(var1, var2) {
  sh 'echo MY values ${var1} and ${var2}'
  sh "echo MY values ${var1} and ${var2}" <-- Works using double quotes, this messes up sed and for-loops...
}
```

**OUTPUT FROM PIPELINE WITH PARAMETERS:**

```
MY values Peace and Space
```

**OUTPUT FROM PIPELINE WITHOUT PARAMETERS:**

```
MY values and
```

I have tried using the `environment{}` keyword as suggested in my previous question, without any luck. [Jenkins - environment](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/environment/)

I am aware that there are similar issues out there:

- [Pass groovy variable to shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41553303/pass-groovy-variable-to-shell-script)
- [How to assign groovy variable to shell variable](https://www.edureka.co/community/56903/how-to-assign-a-groovy-variable-to-a-shell-variable)
- [Jenkins parameters](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters)

**NOTE:**
This is close to a duplicate of my asked quesiton [Shell parameter Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63301406/groovy-parameter-to-shell-script)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED**

I have updated the answer to use environment variable without having `environment {}`

Use environment variables like the ones i have used here (i refactored your code a little bit):

```
def callfunc() {
  sh 'echo MY values $VARENV1 and $VARENV2'
}

pipeline {
    agent { label 'agent_1' }
    stages {
      stage ('Run script') {
        steps {
            script {
                env.VARENV1 = "Peace"
                env.VARENV2 = "Space"
            }
            callfunc()
        }
      }
    }
}
```

`env.VARENV1` and `env.VARENV2` are the environment variables i have used here inside `script{}`. You can assign values to them.

This is my new output:

[image]

I really hope it helped.

**UPDATES FOR USING FOR LOOP**

Using triple single quotes for shell script for loop and adding grrovy variable to it:

```
def callfunc() {
  sh '''
  export s="key"
  echo $s
  for i in $VARENV1 
    do
      echo "Looping ... i is set to $i"
    done
    '''
}

pipeline {
    agent { label 'agent_1' }
    stages {
      stage ('Run script') {
        steps {
            script {
                env.VARENV1 = "Peace"
            }
            callfunc()
        }
      }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: Hi Aditya Nair, thank you for your answer. The main problem I had was to use pass variables to a groovy function which is a bash script. The script that I use is a mixture of groovy-variables and bash-variables. I managed to solve this using the triple-double-quotes `"""` and escaping every bash-variable `\$`.

Comment: I see...I dont know about you but that sounds like a more hectic workaround. The above solution helps you to use groovy variable with `env` prefix that can be used globally throughout the whole pipeline, not to mention  even inside the bash function `callfunc` with single quotes in the script. If you feel like the above solution is a more viable solution, please do give it a try and accept or upvote the answer for the same. Thank you

Comment: I can see you are able to use single quotes `'`, but how will this be if you have shell-variables too, e.g `for in`. Will groovy be able to differentiate these?

Comment: Please check out the answer...i have updated it as per your requirement, you can use triple single quotes and still be able to use the environment variable.

Comment: sorry i left out using the shell variable part...i have updated it...it seems using `export` prefix before variable helps to distinguish it from groovy ones.