# Shell command converting date time into seconds in Jenkins Groovy always returning the same value

Tags: bash, datetime, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have the following code inside a Jenkins Groovy scripted pipeline:

```
def time1     = sh(script: 'date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+00:00"', returnStdout: true).trim()
def time1_sec = sh(script: 'date -d "$time1" +%s', returnStdout: true).trim()
sleep(time: 30, unit: 'SECONDS')
def time2     = sh(script: 'date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+00:00"', returnStdout: true).trim()
def time2_sec = sh(script: 'date -d "$time2" +%s', returnStdout: true).trim()
```

The console logs show that both `time1_sec` and `time2_sec` get the same value, meaning whichever date/time data I convert into seconds, it returns `1709164800`.

```
11:35:12  [Pipeline] sh
11:35:13  + date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+00:00
11:35:13  [Pipeline] sh
11:35:13  + date -d  +%s
11:35:13  [Pipeline] sleep
11:35:13  Sleeping for 30 sec
11:35:43  [Pipeline] sh
11:35:44  + date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+00:00
11:35:44  [Pipeline] sh
11:35:45  + date -d  +%s
11:35:45  [Pipeline] echo
11:35:45  time1    : 2024-02-29T16:35:13+00:00
11:35:45  [Pipeline] echo
11:35:45  time2    : 2024-02-29T16:35:44+00:00
11:35:45  [Pipeline] echo
11:35:45  time1_sec: 1709164800
11:35:45  [Pipeline] echo
11:35:45  time2_sec: 1709164800
```

I used the same shell commands in my Linux terminal, I get the results as expected:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script name: date-time-2-seconds.sh

time1=$(date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+00:00")
time1_sec=$(date -d "$time1" +%s)
sleep 30
time2=$(date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+00:00")
time2_sec=$(date -d "$time2" +%s)

echo "time1    : ${time1}"
echo "time2    : ${time2}"
echo "time1_sec: ${time1_sec}"
echo "time2_sec: ${time2_sec}"

$ ./date-time-2-seconds.sh
time1    : 2024-02-29T16:52:58+00:00
time2    : 2024-02-29T16:53:28+00:00
time1_sec: 1709225578
time2_sec: 1709225608
```

What am I doing wrong in Jenkins Groovy script?

Comment: Your log output suggests that `time1` and `time2` are expanding to empty values. Are you sure that's the correct way to pass variables from Groovy to the shell script?

Comment: From the manual: `An empty [date] string indicates the beginning of the day` so if the expansion is empty then both date commands are going to give you the time as if it were 12 AM.

Comment: Maybe see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41553303/pass-groovy-variable-to-shell-script

Comment: Look at the tracing output you're getting - `11:35:13  + date -d  +%s` with an empty string where `"$time1"` is in your code that's producing that output, `'date -d "$time1" +%s'`.

Comment: I'd be surprised if you can't define all 4 variables without shelling out to `date` at all. Groovy appears to have classes for accessing and manipulating timestamps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String interpolation does not take place in single-quoted strings. You are passing the literal string `date -d "$time1" +%s` to the shell, where no variable named `time1` is defined.

Instead, you need the Groovy variable `time1` to be expanded in a *double*-quoted string, so that the result is visible to the shell as, for example, `date -d "2024-02-29T16:35:13+00:00" +%s`

```
def time1     = sh(script: 'date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+00:00"', returnStdout: true).trim()
def time1_sec = sh(script: "date -d '${time1}' +%s", returnStdout: true).trim()
sleep(time: 30, unit: 'SECONDS')
def time2     = sh(script: 'date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+00:00"', returnStdout: true).trim()
def time2_sec = sh(script: "date -d '${time2}' +%s", returnStdout: true).trim()
```

Note the shell does not care about the difference between single and double quotes in this case, as the values of `time1` and `time2` do not require interpolation by the shell.

Comment: It works but it is not clear to me. If you could please explain it a bit further that would be helpful. You may consider to put the explanation in your answer updating it. Thank you.

Comment: You were mixing Groovy variables with shell variables. In the solution, Groovy itself is replacing the string `${time1}` with the value of the Groovy variable `time1`, so that the fully expanded string is passed to the shell. Your code assumed that, someone, the Groovy variable was used to define a shell variable with the same value so that the *shell* could expand `$time1`. (Basically, the similarity in the syntax used by each makes it confusing to see where the interpolation does/should take place.)

Comment: Honestly, if the answer is confusing, I think you need to spend some more time actually learning the language. I myself don't really know much about Groovy, but string interpolation is a common operation to many languages, and it only took a few moments with the documentation to find this solution.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Yes, I was trying the understanding of shell variables only. I'm good now. Thanks again for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the shell to get a time into groovy?

You can just use [Instant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#getEpochSecond--)

```
def time1_sec = Instant.now().epochSecond
```

Comment: Hi @tim_yates, thanks for your answer, but this is not what I needed. I need the same time I retrieve in two formats: Human readable and epoch.

Comment: Groovy also has facilities for formatting timestamps. `sh` should be reserved for cases where you absolutely *need* to run external commands, not a go-to solution for things that Groovy itself can already do.