# "Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes" with AWS cli on Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-pipeline, amazon-ecs

I am getting an error message

> Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)

while running AWS CLI on Jenkins pipeline to create task definition for EC2 container service. The interesting thing is this script is able to run in command line without any error.

```
aws ecs register-task-definition --family ${FAMILY} --container-definitions "[{\"name\":\"wildfly\",\"image\":\"${REPOSITORY}\",\"memory\":3024,\"essential\":true,\"portMappings\":[{\"containerPort\":8080,\"hostPort\":8080,\"protocol\":\"tcp\"}]}]"`
```

This is the complete error message

> ```
> aws ecs register-task-definition --family wildfly2-b47 --container-definitions [{name:wildfly, image:****/backend:b47, memory:3024, essential:true, portMappings:[{containerPort:8080, hostPort:8080, protocol:tcp}]}]
> ```
>
> Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3
>   (char 2)

This the jenkins stage code

```java
    stage('Deploy')
        withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'ecr-repository', variable: 'repo'), 
        [$class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding', 
        accessKeyVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', 
        credentialsId: 'ecr-credentials', 
        secretKeyVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']]) {
            sh '''
            bash
            set -x
            export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-west-2
            CLUSTER="default"
            VERSION=b${BUILD_NUMBER}
            FAMILY=nxpmp2-${VERSION}
            SERVICE="backend"
            REPOSITORY=${repo}/backend:${VERSION}
            #Register the task definition in the repository
            aws ecs register-task-definition --family ${FAMILY} --container-definitions "[{"name": "wildfly", "image": ${REPOSITORY}, "memory": 3024, "essential": true, "portMappings": [{"containerPort": 8080, "hostPort": 8080, "protocol": "tcp" } ] }]"
            #Update the Service
            #aws ecs update-service --cluster ${CLUSTER} --region ${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION} --service ${SERVICE} --task-definition ${FAMILY}
--desired-count 1
            '''
        }
```

Please help me on this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at the `--container-definitions` part. You see it already with the syntax highlighting:

```
--container-definitions "[{"name":
```

You are using double quotes (around `name`) inside double quotes.

The following should work instead:

```
--container-definitions '[{"name": ...}]'
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above me is problematic if you want to use some groovy variables inside your shell script in the pipeline.

The problem is that aws cli insist on a single quete and then you cant point your froovy variables as follow:

```
FOO = "bar"
sh'''
   aws ecs ...  --container-definitions '[{"name": $FOO}]'
'''
```

this will not give you bar as output but will give $FOO which will result in error.
After a few hours of screwing around and failing to find a clean solution i found a workaround in this post
[Access a Groovy variable from within shell step in Jenkins pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39982414/access-a-groovy-variable-from-within-shell-step-in-jenkins-pipeline)

so the solution is

```
FOO = "bar"
sh'''
   aws ecs ...  --container-definitions '[{"name":''' + $FOO + '''}]'
'''
```

hope i helped