# Defining a variable in shell script portion of Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to dynamically define a variable I use later in a some shell commands of my Jenkins pipeline and it's throwing an exception. I even tried to predefine the variable from an environment section to no avail. Is this a prohibited operation? My other variable `myVar` seems to work fine, but it's a constant through the pipeline.

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent any

   environment {
     py2Ana=""
     myVar="ABCDE"
   }
    stages {
        stage('Stage1') {
            steps {
                sh """
                    echo myVar=$myVar
                    echo Find Anaconda2 Python installation...
                    py2Ana=`which -a python | grep --max-count=1 anaconda2`
                    if [[ -z "$py2Ana" ]]; then
                        echo ERROR: must have a valid Anaconda 2 distribution installed and on the PATH for this job.
                        exit 1 # terminate and indicate error
                    fi
                """
            }
        }
    }
```

### Exception

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: py2Ana for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:242)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:288)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:292)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:268)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:21)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference of strings within single or double quotes in groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761498/whats-the-difference-of-strings-within-single-or-double-quotes-in-groovy)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39982414/access-a-groovy-variable-from-within-shell-step-in-jenkins-pipeline/66637408#66637408

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As @jxramos stated, Jenkins is trying to resolve the variables in the script. It interprets any $string as a variable that needs substitution.
The solution is to escape the $ of the in-script variables, as follows:

```groovy
pipeline { 
  agent any 
  stages {
    stage('test stage'){
      steps {
        sh """#!/bin/bash
            myvar=somevalue
            echo "The value is \$myvar"
        """
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Good addition, I think I came to realize this escaping in a closely related context in another problem I stumbled across when still learning the Jenkinsfile syntax stuff for pipelines https://stackoverflow.com/a/52484384/1330381.

Answer (score 10):

There appears to be a variable substitution precedence that Jenkins enforces in a preprocessing step if you will. In other words there's no *delayed expansion* as one would find in the Windows batch file behavior with `setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`. This explains what's going on, and here's the test pipeline I used to determine this:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent any

   environment {
     py2Ana="DEFAULT"
   }
   stages {
       stage('Stage1') {
           steps {
                sh """
                    echo py2Ana=$py2Ana
                    py2Ana=Initialized
                    echo py2Ana Initialized=$py2Ana
                """
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This yields the following console output...

```
Started by user unknown or anonymous
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] node
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Stage1)
[Pipeline] sh
[TestPipeline] Running shell script
+ echo py2Ana=DEFAULT
py2Ana=DEFAULT
+ py2Ana=Initialized
+ echo py2Ana Initialized=DEFAULT
py2Ana Initialized=DEFAULT
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Another restriction that this poses is that you truly cannot use dynamic variables in the `sh` portion of the Jenkins declarative pipeline script since Jenkins will first attempt to resolve all variables before execution. Thus the following will always yield an error

```groovy
sh """
   for filename in /tmp/**; do
      echo filename=$filename
   done
"""
```

The error being...

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: filename for class: groovy.lang.Binding
```

One would need to define a script dynamically (after figuring out a way to escape the `$` to write to file), or already have it in the source, to be executed.

Comment: thanks for this, I have a question though, imagine you want to use this variable later in your post section? like somewhere in my script I want to have a variable and then use it later in the post when I'm using the ms teams connector in my post section. would this be possible?

Answer (score 5):

The error itself seems really to be caused by the assignment of an empty string.

However: Do you really need that environment variable to be defined in the Jenkinsfile?
To me it looks like you just want to set and read the variable from within the shell script. But the way it's coded the `if [[ -z "$py2Ana" ]]; then` would never pick up the value set by the shell script - it would always want to use a property from the Jenkinsfile - which didn't work.

You could use `if [[ -z "${env.py2Ana}" ]]; then` for the if condition which would fix that error but it still would not pick up the value set by the previous line but always read the empty string set in the Jenkinsfile.

To solve this you could either enclose the string in single quotes for the whole string like (maybe you even want to get rid of the `myVar` then)...:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Stage1') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                    echo Find Anaconda2 Python installation...
                    py2Ana=`which -a python | grep --max-count=1 anaconda2`
                    if [[ -z "$py2Ana" ]]; then
                        echo ERROR: must have a valid Anaconda 2 distribution installed and on the PATH for this job.
                        exit 1 # terminate and indicate error
                    fi
                '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

... or add a backslash right before `$py2Ana` like:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Stage1') {
            steps {
                sh """
                    echo Find Anaconda2 Python installation...
                    py2Ana=`which -a python | grep --max-count=1 anaconda2`
                    if [[ -z "\$py2Ana" ]]; then
                        echo ERROR: must have a valid Anaconda 2 distribution installed and on the PATH for this job.
                        exit 1 # terminate and indicate error
                    fi
                """
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Either way without referencing `env.py2Ana` in the code I doubt the `environment` block in the Jenkinsfile still would make sense - that's why I removed it from the examples.

Answer (score -1):

Just add a value to py2Ana

```
environment {
     py2Ana="1234"
     myVar="ABCDE"
   }
```

It doesn't create the variable in environment if you pass a empty string :)

Comment: You're right that empty strings do not succeed in bringing a variable into scope, good catch. Even still this approach doesn't present an opportunity for my use case however since Jenkins seems to preempt the scripts by an upfront variable substitution with what's known at the scripts interpreter stage. I'll detail my findings in an answer below.