# Define and access a variable in multiple steps of a jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I came here from this post [Defining a variable in shell script portion of Jenkins Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51407976/defining-a-variable-in-shell-script-portion-of-jenkins-pipeline)

My situation is the following I have a pipeline that is updating some files and generating a PR in my repo if there are changes in the generated files (they change every couple of weeks or less).

At the end of my pipeline I have a post action to send the result by email to our teams connector.

I wanted to know if I could somehow generate a variable and include that variable in my email.

It looks something like this but off course it does not work.

```
#!groovy
String WasThereAnUpdate = '';

pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        GRADLE_OPTS = '-Dorg.gradle.java.home=$JAVA11_HOME'
    }
    stages {
        stage('File Update') {
            steps {
                sh './gradlew updateFiles -P updateEnabled'
            }
        }
        stage('Create PR') {
            steps {
                withCredentials(...) {
                    sh '''
                        if [ -n \"$(git status --porcelain)\" ]; then
                            WasThereAnUpdate=\"With Updates\"
                            ...
                        else
                            WasThereAnUpdate=\"Without updates\"
                        fi
                    '''
                }
            }    
        }
    }
    post {
        success {
            office365ConnectorSend(
                message: "Scheduler finished: " + WasThereAnUpdate,
                status: 'Success',
                color: '#1A5D1C',
                webhookUrl: 'https://outlook.office.com/webhook/1234'
            )
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried referencing my variable in different ways ${}, etc... but I'm pretty sure that assignment is not working.
I know I probably could do it with a script block but I'm not sure how I would put the script block inside the SH itself, not sure this would be possible.

Thanks to the response from MaratC https://stackoverflow.com/a/64572833/5685482 and this [documentation](https://e.printstacktrace.blog/jenkins-pipeline-environment-variables-the-definitive-guide/)
I'll do it something like this:

```
#!groovy
def date = new Date()
String newBranchName = 'protoUpdate_'+date.getTime()

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('ensure a diff') {
            steps {
                sh 'touch oneFile.txt'
            }
        }
        stage('AFTER') {
            steps {
                script {
                    env.STATUS2 = sh(script:'git status --porcelain', returnStdout: true).trim()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        success {
            office365ConnectorSend(
                message: "test ${env.STATUS2}",
                status: 'Success',
                color: '#1A5D1C',
                webhookUrl: 'https://outlook.office.com/webhook/1234'
            )
        }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code

```
sh '''
    if [ -n \"$(git status --porcelain)\" ]; then
        WasThereAnUpdate=\"With Updates\"
        ...
    else
        WasThereAnUpdate=\"Without updates\"
    fi
'''
```

Your code creates a `sh` session (most likely `bash`). That session inherits the environment variables from the process that started it (Jenkins). Once it runs `git status`, it then sets a `bash` variable `WasThereAnUpdate` (which is a different variable from likely named Groovy variable.)

This `bash` variable is what gets updated in your code.

Once your `sh` session ends, `bash` process gets destroyed, and all of its variables get destroyed too.

This whole process has no influence whatsoever on Groovy variable named `WasThereAnUpdate` that just stays what it was before.

Comment: yes that part is more or less what I was expecting, so there is no way of defining any kind of assignment in the SH section? even if I used an environment setting?

Comment: I'll try to look into this, see if I can store what I need in our environment setting 
https://e.printstacktrace.blog/jenkins-pipeline-environment-variables-the-definitive-guide/

Comment: You can put your code in script that will print either `With Updates` or `Without Updates` and run `def UpdatesOutput = sh script: "myscript.sh", returnStdout: true`. Groovy variable named `UpdatesOutput` will then hold the output of the script.