# jenkins passing in path to python argument as variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

in jenkins i have :

```
  sh 'ls ${workspace}'
  sh 'cd MVD/utils && python compareWhitelist.py ${workspace}/MVDZOS'
```

I want to pass the complete path into the python script because I am doing

```
os.walk(sys.argv[1])
```

in the python script, I am also printing out the sys.argv[1] but it is returning only "/MVDZOS". How can I get the complete path into the script?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50940512/4279361

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Uppercase in quotes.

**Ex:**

```
sh 'ls ${workspace}'
sh "cd MVD/utils && python compareWhitelist.py ${WORKSPACE}/MVDZOS"
```

Comment: That won’t work. You‘ll need to use double quotes for the sh step.