# Access a groovy variable from within shell in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40078286/3317808) did not help me

Below is the method in groovy:

```
def analyze(repoName){

        result= sh (
                    script: '''
                            cd ${WORKSPACE}/${BUILD_NUMBER}
                            cat > sonar-project.properties << EOF_$$
sonar.projectKey=ABC-$repoName
sonar.projectName=ABC
sonar.projectBaseDir=${WORKSPACE}/${BUILD_NUMBER}
EOF_$$
                            ''',
                    returnStatus: true
                    ) == 0
        print "Creating file - Return status: ${result}"
  }
```

---

where below line gives error:

`sonar.projectKey=ABC-$repoName`

properties file gets created with entry `sonar.projectKey=ABC-`

---

How to use groovy variable in `sh()` step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should double quotes for string interpolation and escape `$` by `\$` in following places:

- `${WORKSPACE}` and `${BUILD_NUMBER}`, you intent to use them as bash environment variable, rather than groovy variable
- `EOF_$$`, you intent to use it literal meaning

Changed code:

```
def analyze(repoName){

        result= sh (
                    script: """
                            cd \${WORKSPACE}/\${BUILD_NUMBER}
                            cat > sonar-project.properties << EOF_\$\$
sonar.projectKey=ABC-$repoName
sonar.projectName=ABC
sonar.projectBaseDir=\${WORKSPACE}/\${BUILD_NUMBER}
EOF_\$\$
                            """,
                    returnStatus: true
                    ) == 0
        print "Creating file - Return status: ${result}"
  }
```

Comment: So that means, before above script goes to shell, $ will interpolate and \$ will not interpolate. Is the idea?

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct. For more detail about string in Groovy, please read http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#all-strings

Answer (score 2):

You should use double quotes for string interpolation, so just replace `'''`with `"""`

And change `EOF_$$` to `EOF_\$\$`

Comment: I see errors for lines `cd ${WORKSPACE}` and `cat > sonar-project.properties << EOF_$$` after replacing `'''` with `"""`. Illegal string body

Comment: @overexchange, check out the documentation of string usage in groovy: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#all-strings. `$` is a special char in double strings. You take advantage of that in variable interpolation so it needs to be escaped otherwise.

Comment: @OliverGondža is right, you have to escape $ sign too

Comment: I also need to `cd \${WORKSPACE}/\${BUILD_NUMBER}`, which I do not understand.. why?

Comment: Do you? Because it worked for me without escaping `$` in this line, can you show the full script you are trying to execute?