# How to access variables out of a sh script inside a Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

The following code is a very simplified version of my code just for a better explanation:

```
def String FOLDER_NAME = "TestFolder"

def createFolder() {
    sh('''
        ls
        mkdir ${FOLDER_NAME}
        ls
    ''')
}
```

I want to use the name, stored inside the FOLDER_NAME variable, to create a new folder. The problem is that the current code does not use it. My first approach was to use ' ' around the variable access like this:

```
def createFolder() {
    sh('''
        ls
        mkdir '${FOLDER_NAME}'
        ls
    ''')
}
```

But this creates a new folder called ${FOLDER_NAME} and does not use the variable value.

My question is, how do I have to change my code so that it uses the **variable value**, not the variable call?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference of strings within single or double quotes in groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761498/whats-the-difference-of-strings-within-single-or-double-quotes-in-groovy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution will be resolved by [differentiating between groovy's single and double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761498/whats-the-difference-of-strings-within-single-or-double-quotes-in-groovy).

String replacements are done inside double quotes `""` only. Therefore, to resolve the issue just change `sh` command to:

```
def createFolder() {
    sh("""
        ls
        mkdir '${FOLDER_NAME}'
        ls
    """)
}
```