# How can I force Jenkins Blue Ocean to display print output instead of "Print Message"?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

In the below screenshot some debug entries display the output text (with `- Print Message` at the end) while others simply display `Print Message`. To view these you have to expand the step to see the output.

[image: Jenkins Blue Ocean Output]

All lines are using the format `print "TEXT HERE"`. I've tried using `print`, `println`, and `echo`. All have the same output.

Why do these sometimes display the message, while others force it into a collapsed section? Is it possible to configure this to always show? The normal non-Blue Ocean Jenkins interface displays fine but there is a lot of verbosity.

Comment: I've noticed this too. It's not very useful. Short answer is, I don't think you can. Having implemented a plugin recently, I realised it is the display name for the pipeline step provided by the plugin that implements it. From here look for the getDisplayName() method: https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-basic-steps-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/steps/EchoStep.java

Comment: Having the same issue and can't understand how 5 different lines print out with and without "Print Message" using echo.

Comment: Got into this same problem today... I noticed that if you call a step embedded into another shared library, all the statements print link that... Still investigating...

Comment: I'm here again... No signs of identifying the reasons why this happens...

Answer (score 7):

This seems to be a known issue:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-53649

It looks like that BlueOcean does not handle the Groovy GStrings correctly. This is what I've observed:

A simple:

```
echo "hello world"
```

will work as expected and will display correctly.
Whereas a templated string with variables, like:

```
echo "hello ${some_variable}"
```

will hide the message under a "Print Message" dropdown.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6761591/3728153).

Answer (score 6):

It appears that if echo uses a variable with value from params or environment (i.e. "params.*"), then step label gets "Print message" name instead of actual value being echoed. It does not matter if the variable itself is a String or not. Even explicitly converting the params value to String does not help.

```
String param_str
String text_var_2

parameters {
    string(name: 'str_param', defaultValue: 'no value')
}

                param_str = params.str_param.toString()

                echo "string text in double quotes is ${param_str}"
                echo "simple quoted string is here"
                echo 'simple quoted string is here' 
                echo 'Single quoted with str ' + param_str + ' is here'
                echo param_str                    
                text_var_2 = 'Single quoted str ' + param_str + ' combined' 
                echo "GString global text2 is ${text_var_2}" 
                echo 'String global text2 is' +  text_var_2
```

BlueOcean shows simple quoted strings in step label, but everything else as "Print message".

[BlueOcean output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIQPK.png)

Note that 'normal' variables (strings, integers) are not included into this example, but they are also shown in the label normally. So if you have a code like this

```
def text_str = 'Some string'
def int_var = 1+2
echo text_str + ' is here'
echo int_var
```

These will be shown on the label.

And indeed it appears to be a known Jenkins issue as stated in a previous answer.

Answer (score 5):

This is a known [BlueOcean bug](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-53649). The console output in the "classic" view interpolates variables correctly.

One workaround is to use the `label` parameter of the [sh step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script):

```
def message = 'Hello World'
sh(script: "echo $message", label: message)
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried lots of things and seems the moment an environment variable is going to be displayed, it uses Print Message instead the text.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround would be to split the multiline string into an array and iterate over it :-

```
 String[] splitData = MULTI_LINE_STRING.split("\n");
     for (String eachSplit : splitData) {
         print(eachSplit);
      }
```