# passing values from pipeline to shell script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

I have a pipeline where i have TARGETENVIRONMENT as QA and PROD.In the first step I am converting TARGETENVIRONMENT and storing that value in variable Ajob and Bjob.These values Ajob and Bjob are job names where i need to get the build number for processing further.

```
def Ajob = "ProjectBuild_ABD_${TARGET_PLATFORM.toUpperCase()}_fe"
def Bjob = "ProjectBuild_ABD_${TARGET_PLATFORM.toUpperCase()}_be"
```

In the next step I am storing the build numbers of these jobs.When i

```
def fe = sh returnStdout: true, script: '/usr/sfw/bin/wget -qO- http://fiesccet01.emea.nsn-net.net:9095/job/${Ajob}/lastBuild/buildNumber'
def be = sh returnStdout: true, script: '/usr/sfw/bin/wget -qO- http://fiesccet01.emea.nsn-net.net:9095/job/${Bjob}/lastBuild/buildNumber'
```

The script is not taking these values ${Ajob} and ${Bjob}.How to pass these variables in the script.

Comment: try removing the def before each Ajob and Bjob declaration

Comment: maybe you also want to try the [`httpRequest`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/http_request/#httprequest-perform-an-http-request-and-return-a-response-object) step. This will not solve your current problem in any way, but would look a bit nicer than calling `wget`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference of strings within single or double quotes in groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761498/whats-the-difference-of-strings-within-single-or-double-quotes-in-groovy)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```java
def fe = sh returnStdout: true, script: "/usr/sfw/bin/wget -qO- http://fiesccet01.emea.nsn-net.net:9095/job/${Ajob}/lastBuild/buildNumber"
def be = sh returnStdout: true, script: "/usr/sfw/bin/wget -qO- http://fiesccet01.emea.nsn-net.net:9095/job/${Bjob}/lastBuild/buildNumber"
```

The difference is that the strings are using double quotes, which apply [string interpolation](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation), i.e. replace variables, in contrast to single quotes, which don't.