# Jenkins function definition: call a batch file using function arguments

Tags: batch-file, jenkins-pipeline

Here is a chunk of code I have in a pipeline:

```groovy
def doBuild(folder, script, scriptArguments = '') {
   bat '''cd folder
          call script scriptArgument'''
}
```

So basically, it is a windows command saying: move to this directory, and call this script.

Of course, during execution, the command will be executed as 'cd folder' and will fail.

How can I make sure the 'folder' is replaced by the value passed in argument ?

Edit:

Following the suggestion of Vitalii, I tried the following code:

```
/* Environment Properties */
repository_name = 'toto'
extra_repository_branch = 'master'
branch_to_build = "${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
version = "${branch_to_build}_v1.5.4.${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"

/* Methods definitions properties */
def doTag() {
    dir(repository_name) {
        String tagCommand = """git tag -m "Release tag ${env.BUILD_URL}" ${version}"""
        String pushCommand = "git push --tags origin ${branch_to_build}"

        bat '''
            call $tagCommand
            call $pushCommand'''
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

> C:\Jenkins\toto>call $tagCommand  '$tagCommand' is not recognized
>   as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
>
> C:\Jenkins\toto>call $pushCommand  '$pushCommand' is not
>   recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or
>   batch file.

Thanks very much for your time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference of strings within single or double quotes in groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761498/whats-the-difference-of-strings-within-single-or-double-quotes-in-groovy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [string interpolation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_string_interpolation)

```
bat """cd $folder
     call $script $scriptArgument"""
```

Comment: Thank you, now maybe you can answer a question I had for a moment, what is the clear difference between $foo and ${foo} ?

Thanks

Comment: They are almost the same except second one allows dotted expressions. For example `"${foo.split(',')}"`

Comment: In the case of my script, ${folder} was read literraly and the command sent to windows was 'cd ${folder}'
Is there a reason why $folder will work while ${folder} won't ?

Comment: Hi Vitalii, unfortunately it is not working, I have edited my original post, may you have a look ?

Answer (score 1):

So I did not think it was the case first but it was really had its answer in [What's the difference of strings within single or double quotes in groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761498/whats-the-difference-of-strings-within-single-or-double-quotes-in-groovy)

Using single quotes, the text is considered as literrate. Using double code, it will interpret correctly the $tagCommand. A working version is:

```
/* Methods definitions properties */

def doTag() {
    dir(repository_name) {
        String tagCommand = """git tag -m "Release tag ${env.BUILD_URL}" ${version}"""
        String pushCommand = "git push --tags origin ${branch_to_build}"

        bat """call $tagCommand
            call $pushCommand"""
    }
}
```