# setting environment variable in jenkins scripted pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Im trying to set a environment variable(VIRTUALENV) in Jenkins - stage(check_style) and use that in the shell but it throws a error.

```
withEnv(['VIRTUAL_ENV=${env.WORKSPACE}/venv']){
            stage ('Check_style') {
                 sh """
                    export PATH=${VIRTUAL_ENV}/bin:${PATH}
                    make flake8 | tee report/flake8.log || true
                """
  }
  }
```

Error:-

```
PATH=${env.WORKSPACE}/venv/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin: bad substitution
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference of strings within single or double quotes in groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761498/whats-the-difference-of-strings-within-single-or-double-quotes-in-groovy)

Comment: Use single quotes

Answer (score 1):

`withEnv(["VIRTUAL_ENV=${env.WORKSPACE}/venv"])`  should work