# How can I read Jenkins pipeline variable in multiline shell?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to create a Jenkins pipeline where I need to execute multiline shell commands.

```
stage ('Test'){
name="myserver"
sh '''
    "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${myserver} 'rm -rf temp && mkdir -p temp && mkdir -p real'"
'''

}
```

But it is always returning error as "command not found". If I run the same with

```
sh "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${myserver} 'rm -rf temp && mkdir -p temp && mkdir -p real' "
```

Is there a different way to access variable in multiline shell?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference of strings within single or double quotes in groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761498/whats-the-difference-of-strings-within-single-or-double-quotes-in-groovy)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use """ like this:

```
sh """
    "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${myserver} 'rm -rf temp && mkdir -p temp && mkdir -p real'"
"""
```