# when use jenkins pipeline shared library ,the function parameters in sh ''' ''' will be null

Tags: jenkins, groovy, shared-libraries, jenkins-pipeline

`/var/coverityCompile.groovy`

```groovy
#!groovy
def java(String DIR) {
    compile_dir="${WORKSPACE}/${DIR}"
    echo "complie_dir:${compile_dir}"
    sh "echo complie_dir:${compile_dir}"
    sh '''
    echo complie_dir:${compile_dir}
    '''
}
```

`/src/org/coverity/JenkinsFile`

```groovy
#!groovy
@Library('shared-library') _
   pipeline {
    agent { label 'dev_ci_env_dm' }
    stages {
        stage('coverity'){
            steps{
                script{
                    coverityCompile.java("DM")
                }

            }
        }
}
}
```

The Jenkins log will be:

```
complie_dir:/home/ci/workspace/test_coverity/DM
[Pipeline] sh
[test_coverity] Running shell script
+ echo complie_dir:/home/ci/workspace/test_coverity/DM
complie_dir:/home/ci/workspace/test_coverity/DM
complie_dir:
```

when I use `echo "complie_dir:${compile_dir}"`
and `sh "echo complie_dir:${compile_dir}"`
the result will be printed as expected. But, when I use

```groovy
sh '''
    echo complie_dir:${compile_dir}
'''
```

The result of ${compile_dir} will be null.
Now, I want to execute multiline of shell,so is there any other way to replace `sh ''' '''`?

Comment: `'` does not interpolate variables. You need `"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference of strings within single or double quotes in groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761498/whats-the-difference-of-strings-within-single-or-double-quotes-in-groovy)