# ext-email plugin, Not sending emails to default recipients from pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to send emails from a Jenkins scripted pipeline with help of the ext-email plugin.

I have configured the plugin with Default Recipients.

Here is my pipeline:

```
node {
  try {
    echo "hi"
  } catch (e) {
    currentBuild.result = "FAILED"
    notifyBuild(currentBuild.result)
    throw e
  }
  finally {
    notifyBuild(currentBuild.result)
  }
}

def notifyBuild(String buildStatus = 'STARTED') {
  buildStatus =  buildStatus ?: 'SUCCESSFUL'
  def subject = "${buildStatus}: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]'"
  def summary = "${subject} (${env.BUILD_URL})"
  def details = """
  <p>STARTED: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]':</p>
  <p>Check console output at "<a href="${env.BUILD_URL}">${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]</a>"</p>
  """ 
  emailext (
    subject: subject,
    body: details,
    attachLog: true,
    to: ${DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS},
    recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider'], [$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider'], [$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider']]
  )
}
```

I trying to send the email to a user who triggered the job but I did not get emails to DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS. I also tried with `to: env.DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS`.

I am getting this error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: $DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS for class: groovy.lang.Binding
```

Answer (score 7):

I also having same problem, just now I got solution on this check the below step:

```
emailext body: '''${SCRIPT, template="groovy-html.template"}''', 
        subject: "${env.JOB_NAME} - Build # ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} - Successful", 
        mimeType: 'text/html',to: '$DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS'
```

note down the single qoutes around `$DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS` that is the key to success here.

I don't know why is not working with double qoutes :(

Comment: That's why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761498/whats-the-difference-of-strings-within-single-or-double-quotes-in-groovy

Answer (score -1):

You should go to Manage Jenkins->Configure System->Extended E-mail Notification. There you should fill the Default Recipient field and Save. (If you do not have the Email Extension Plugin, please install it).

Then you can use the `$DEFAULT_RECIPIENT` variable in the 'to' clause. Please, remove the braces.

Hope this helps.

Comment: When I try this, I just get an error -> `No such property: DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS`. 
Note that the actual variable is DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS, not DEFAULT_RECIPIENT. Same result for both.
Code: 
`emailext (
                  to: "$DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS",
                  subject: "STARTED: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]'",
                  body: """<p>STARTED: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]':</p>
                    <p>Check console output at "<a href="${env.BUILD_URL}">${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]</a>"</p>""")
            }`