# Use a ${variable} in a sh command in a jenkinsfile

Tags: maven, jenkins, escaping, jenkins-pipeline, sh

I'm trying to use this maven command in a Jenkinsfile

```
mvn -q -Dexec.executable=echo -Dexec.args='${project.version}' --non-recursive exec:exec
```

I put this command in a variable in my jenkinsfile to use it later this way

```
def myCommand = 'mvn -q -Dexec.executable=echo -Dexec.args=\"${project.version}\" --non-recursive exec:exec'
```

...

```
def version = sh(${myCommand})
```

My problem is that Jenkins don't correctly escape my '${project.version}' and outputs `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method '$' found among steps`

How do I correctly include '${project.version}' as a string in my command variable ?

Comment: In most interpretive languages, including this one, `'` denotes string literals and `"` denotes string interpolation. You want the latter, but are using the former. Sorry to say, but this is also a question with at least ten duplicates on SO right now. As a side node, in string literals you do not need to escape a `"` within the string like you are doing, but that point is moot for your given usage.

Comment: I recommend to use: `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:3.1.1:evaluate -Dproject.version -DforceStdout -q` instead of exec plugin...

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with single quote in groovy - it doesn't substitute the variables. This should work:

```
def myCommand = "mvn -q -Dexec.executable=echo -Dexec.args='${project.version}' --non-recursive exec:exec"
```

More on the quotes: [What's the difference of strings within single or double quotes in groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761498/whats-the-difference-of-strings-within-single-or-double-quotes-in-groovy)

Comment: Nope... Now it's trying to resolve project inside the Jenkinsfile
`groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: project for class: groovy.lang.Binding`

Comment: No... Your solution prevent the pipeline from running. I tried to echo mine and I got the same output : `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method '$' found among steps `

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the single quotes with double quotes:

```
def myCommand = "mvn -q -Dexec.executable=echo -Dexec.args=\"${project.version}\" --non-recursive exec:exec"
```

Comment: It's not working : Jenkins tries to resolve project
`groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: project for class: groovy.lang.Binding`

I'm not trying to inject project.version, I'm trying to include ${project.version} in the  myCommand var.